# Can I make this function defenition even shorter?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, currying, ramda.js

I am trying move more towards functional programming in my javascript applications. I currently use the library [ramda](http://ramdajs.com) as a base lib for this.

#### My desire:

1. Create a function `findWithId(id, list)` which returns the item in the list with the property `_id` matching the input id.
2. Make the implementation of it as short as possible, relying on existing code as much as possible.

#### Acheived so far:

My base is `R.find` which has this defenition

`find :: (a -> Boolean) -> [a] -> a | undefined`

I tried some different solutions shown below:

```
//Using ramdajs (ramdajs.com)
var hasId = R.curry(function(id, item) {
  return item._id === id
});

//This doesn't work
var findWithId_v1 = R.find(hasId);

//This works but can I make it as short as v1?
var findWithId_v2 = function(id, list) {
  return R.find(hasId(id), list);
}
```

#### Question

Can I make `findWithId_v2` as short as `findWithId_v1` by using standard functional  programming tools like compose, curry etc?

#### Plunker demo

http://plnkr.co/edit/xAYx15yk6lBzutdAL9HC?p=preview

Comment: __[Why over-complicate things?](http://plnkr.co/edit/NKcKGw2HApvSV71yhi9D?p=preview)__

Comment: Or even better, __[just iterate over the array with angular.](http://plnkr.co/edit/Csl0O8ixGkrLWorDameM?p=preview)__

Comment: That is not necessarily what I want to do. I want to understand FP and if I know this is possible then I can utilize it in many places. If I know it is not, then I wont be (constantly) bothered about considering whether I can improve my code or not.

Comment: @Cerbrus After reading you second comment, I don't think you understand the question and or subject matter.

Comment: Okay, _why_ do you want to do it with this library? Why do you want to _"move more towards functional programming"_?

Comment: @Cerbrus: Just because `var findWithId = R.compose(R.find, R.propEq('_id'))` is so much more concise than `var findWithId = R.curry(function(id, list) {
  return R.find((function(item) {
  return item._id === id
}, list);
})` ? :-)

Comment: Why use this library in the first place? Writing functions for the sake of functional programming hardly seems efficient. Especially if what you're doing can be replaced by a single `ng-repeat` statement.

Comment: @Cerbrus This is not about angular!!! I use angular in my plunk to show the desired result. If you want to get introduced to functional programming, please check the video link. I am not responding to anything more in this particular discussion. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m3svKOdZijA

Comment: Way to over-complicate logging the result o.O

Comment: @Cerbrus: Agreed about the logging, but there are plenty of good reasons to use a higher-level library.  (Of course as one of the authors of the library in question, perhaps I'm biased!  :-) )  But the points-free solution in my answer is fairly simple and readable, once you know the constructs involved.  Granted, `useWith` is still reasonably obscure, but it wasn't that long ago that people said the same about `map`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ramda does have a function that will help with this, one called `useWith`.  If you can think of a better name, I'd love it.  I've [asked that before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17386706/).

You can use is like this:

```
var findById = R.useWith(R.find, hasId, R.identity);

var find5 = findById(5);
find5([{id:3}, {id:5}]); //=> {id:5} 
findById(5, [{id:3}, {id:5}]); //=> {id:5}
```

You don't have to supply `R.identity` above.  This would also work, although I prefer to be explicit:

```
var findById = R.useWith(R.find, hasId);
```

[useWith](http://ramdajs.com/R.html#useWith) "accepts a function `fn` and any number of transformer functions and returns a new function. When the new function is invoked, it calls the function `fn` with parameters consisting of the result of calling each supplied handler on successive arguments to the new function"

Comment: Wonderful. Being new to FP I only wonder if "useWith" is a generic concept or specific to ramda.

Comment: I did [ask that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17386706/) but no one seemed to have a good answer.  Part of the issue is that with a language like Haskell, where every function takes only a single parameter, this is never a problem, and I think the question just leads to confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [`compose`](http://ramdajs.com/docs#compose) function:

```
compose :: (a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> (a -> c)
hasId :: p -> (i -> Boolean)
find :: (i -> Boolean) -> ([i] -> i | undefined)
compose :: (p -> (i -> Boolean))
           -> ((i -> Boolean) -> ([i] -> i | undefined))
           -> (p -> ([i] -> i | undefined))
compose find hasId :: p -> ([i] -> i | undefined)
```

So you'd do

```
var findWithId = R.compose(R.find, hasId)
```

Oh, and notice that you don't need a function expression for `hasId` either:

```
var hasId = R.propEq('_id');
```

Comment: Does not seem to work, check updated plnkr (same link as in question).

Comment: Plnkr doesn't work for me, but I'm still testing; you might be right

Comment: Actually  `findWithId(5)([{_id:3}, {_id:5}])` does seem to work for me

Comment: Ah, but not findWithId(5,[{_id:3}, {_id:5}]). One function taking two arguments. You had a function taking one argument, that returned another function which also took one argument.

Comment: Yes, because compose works with curried functions... You can see from the type signature that `compose find hasId` gives you a function that takes an `a` (= `p`), a returns a `c` - which is = `([i] -> i|undefined)`

Comment: It seems there is no `uncurry` method as of now that can transform this back into a function that takes multiple arguments…

Comment: What do you mean? Curried functions can take multiple arguments.

Comment: Well, not this one, because it *doesn't know* that it is curried (returns a function). This "syntax sugar" of "multiple arguments" doesn't work here.

Comment: I now understand what you meant. Did not know of uncurry before.