# How can I compose a function so that an inner application implicitly receives an outer argument?

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

**EDIT**: I've marked this as a duplicate of [Can I make this function defenition [sic] even shorter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26178152/4525), which is functionally identical (*two* puns intended) and has a good answer from one of the authors of the Ramda library.

This is a question more of academic curiosity than practical need.

I'm trying out the [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/docs/) library, which emphasises a "point-free" style of function composition.

Suppose I have an array of objects, like

```
var things = [
    {id: "a", value: 234},
    {id: "b", value: 345},
    {id: "c", value: 456}
]
```

and I wanted a function to return the element by id (or at least, for the moment, a list matching by id).  In native javascript, I can say

```
var byId = function(id, arr) { return arr.filter(function(o) { return o.id === id; }); };
```

then `byId('c', things)` will give me an array containing just the third item.

In Ramda, I can do this more concisely and with no reference to the data:

```
var byIdRam = function(id) { return R.filter(R.propEq('id', id)); }
```

The result is a "curried" function, so  `byIdRam('c')(things)` gives the same result as the first version.

I sense that the remaining lambda is also unnecessary, but I don't know how to compose the function without explicit reference to the id.  Does anyone know a better way to write this?

**UPDATE** The answer is simply

```
var byId = R.useWith(R.find, R.propEq('id'))
```

This also gives the semantics I want, where it either returns a single element or `undefined`.  Nice!

Comment: Do you want to create a function that could be invoked like `byId()` and return the same as `byId('c', things)`?

Comment: @seva.rubbo, yes -- at least that is consistent with the library.  However, in practice I'd probably want the element found or `null` in return.  I was trying to factor that out for the sake of the question.

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right you need something like this:

```
var byIdC = function () {

    var results = things.filter(function (o) {return o.id === "c";})

    return results.length ? results[0] : null;

};
```

Or with your Ramda library:

```
var byIdC = function () {

    var results = R.filter(R.propEq("id", "c"))(things);

    return results.length ? results[0] : null;

};
```