# To "combine" functions in javascript in a functional way?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I'm learning functional programming and I wonder if there is a way to "combine" functions like this:

```
function triple(x) {
    return x * 3;
}
function plusOne(x) {
    return x + 1;
}
function isZero(x) {
    return x === 0;
}
combine(1); //1
combine(triple)(triple)(plusOne)(1); // 10
combine(plusOne)(triple)(isZero)(-1); // true
```

If the para is a function, it "combines" the function into itself, and if not it will return the final result. 
Thanks!

Comment: @u_mulder parameter i guess

Comment: the question is not clear at the point of "combines" the function

Comment: the following code works since it returns a function ... `x = function(){return function(b){return b*2}}; x()(2) == 4` ... not what you want though

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**heritage**

This is a concept from maths called [function composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition).

```
       f(x) = y
       g(y) = z

    g(f(x)) = z

   (g•f)(x) = z
```

That last line is read *"g of f of x equals z"*. What's great about composed functions is the elimination of *points*. Notice in `g(f(x)) = z` we take an `x` input and get a `z` output. This skips the intermediate point, `y`.

Composition is a great way to create [higher-order functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) and keep your code sparkly clean. It's plain to see why we'd want this in our Javascript programs.

---

**comp**

JavaScript is a multi-paradigm language with rich support for functions. We can create a simple `comp` function, which combines two input functions, `g` and `f`, and results in a *new* function -

```js
function triple(x) {
  return x * 3
}

function plusOne(x) {
  return x + 1
}

function comp(g, f) {
  return function(x) {
    return g(f(x))        // "g of f of x"
  }
}

const myfunc =
  comp(triple, plusOne)

console.log(myfunc(1))
```

Evaluation

```js
triple(plusOne(1))
triple(2)
6
```

---

**compose**

Just as the question suggests, it's likely we will want to combine more than two functions. Below we write `compose` which takes `all` of the input functions and `reduce`s them using our simple `comp` from above. If no functions are given, we return the empty function, `identity` -

```js
const triple = (x) =>
  x * 3

const plusOne = (x) =>
  x + 1

const comp = (g, f) =>
  x => g(f(x))                     // "g of f of x"

const identity = (x) =>
  x

const compose = (...all) =>
  all.reduce(comp, identity)

const myfunc =
  compose(triple, triple, plusOne) // any amount of funcs

console.log(myfunc(1))
```

Evaluation

```js
triple(triple(plusOne(1)))
triple(triple(2))
triple(6)
18
```

---

**pipe**

You can be as creative as you like. Below, we write `pipe` which allows our programs to read in a comfortable left-to-right direction -

```js
const triple = (x) =>
  x * 3

const plusOne = (x) =>
  x + 1

const pipe = x =>
  f => pipe(f(x))

pipe(1)(plusOne)(triple)(triple)(console.log)           // 18
pipe(3)(triple)(plusOne)(triple)(plusOne)(console.log)  // 31
```

Evaluation of expression one -

```js
f => pipe(f(1))
pipe(plusOne(1))
f => pipe(f(2))
pipe(triple(2))
f => pipe(f(6))
pipe(triple(6))
f => pipe(f(18))
pipe(console.log(18))
18
```

and expression two -

```js
f => pipe(f(3))
pipe(triple(3))
f => pipe(f(9))
pipe(plusOne(9))
f => pipe(f(10))
pipe(triple(10))
f => pipe(f(30))
pipe(plusOne(31))
f => pipe(f(31))
pipe(console.log(31))
31
```

---

**related techniques**

*Curried functions* and *partial application* are concepts that gel with function composition. `pipe` above is introduced in [another Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32787782/633183) as `$` and demonstrated again here -

```js
const $ = x =>           // "pipe", or whatever name you pick
  k => $ (k (x))
  
const add = x => y =>    // curried add
  x + y

const mult = x => y =>   // curried mult
  x * y
  
$ (1)                    // 1
  (add (2))              // + 2 = 3
  (mult (6))             // * 6 = 18
  (console.log)          // 18
  
$ (7)                    // 7
  (add (1))              // + 1 = 8
  (mult (8))             // * 8 = 64
  (mult (2))             // * 2 = 128
  (mult (2))             // * 2 = 256
  (console.log)          // 256
```

Comment: Excellent! I spent a long time reading it and it helps me a lot. Thanks for your great work!

Comment: @user3016883 I found a couple typos and fixed them up. If you ran into trouble, I hope the edits help ^.^

Comment: Related: [How to correctly curry a function in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27996544/783743)

Comment: great answer, but it's quite missing the fact that as long as the first param is a function, then it should curry indefinitely: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65537611/4099454. whereas your version does not seem to curry at all

Comment: Hitmands, I've been meaning to rework this answer for some time. Thanks to your respected review I finally got around to it :D

Comment: I'm having a hard time seeing how to use these if you want to do something with the values besides write them to the console. `pipe(1)(plusOne)(triple)(triple)(console.log) ` correctly prints 18 to the console, but `z=pipe(1)(plusOne)(triple)(triple)` doesn't assigned the value 18 to `z`, in fact it assigns a function to `z`. How do you capture the end result in a variable to use later?

Comment: if you want to _"do something"_, `console.log` is just an example, you can replace it with any other function that does another thing. assigning to a variable like in direct style is not the only way to write a program. if you really must get the data "out", you can modify `pipe` to check `f == null` or some other sentinel and conditionally return `x`.

Answer (score 1):

```
function triple(x) {
    return x * 3;
}
function plusOne(x) {
    return x + 1;
}
function isZero(x) {
    return x === 0;
}

var combine = function (v) {
    var fn = [];
    function _f(v) {
        if (typeof v === 'function') {
            fn.push(v);
            return _f;
        } else {
            return fn.reduce(function (x, f) { return f(x); }, v);
        }
    }
    return _f(v);
};

var a, b;
console.log(combine(1)); //1
console.log(combine(triple)(triple)(plusOne)(1)); // 10
console.log(combine(plusOne)(triple)(isZero)(-1)); // true
console.log(a = combine(plusOne)); // function ...
console.log(b = a(triple)); // function ...
console.log(b(5)); // 18
console.log(combine(triple)(plusOne)(triple)(plusOne)(triple)(plusOne)(1)); // 40
// @naomik's examples
var f = combine(triple); 
var g = combine(triple)(triple); 
console.log(f(1)); // 3
console.log(g(1)); // 9 (not 6 as you stated)
```

Comment: Make two functions: `var f = combine(triple); var g = combine(triple)(triple);` Call `f(1); // 27`, then call `g(1) // 1`.  Obviously `f(1) // should be 3` and `g(1) // should be 6`.  This fails because you're depending on the user to finish a chain before creating a new one. The problem is `combine.fn` is stateful and subsequent calls to `combine` will result in the `fn` state of other functions being mutated.

Comment: i know this problem, but what result do you expect with `combine(triple)(triple);`? the call ends alway with a value, so the rule is function* value (bfn).

Comment: i expect `combine(triple)(triple)` to create a new function for me that i can assign to variable, call at a later time, or pass as a value to another function. Just as I demonstrated with `f` and `g` above.

Comment: I've removed my down-vote as you've provided an answer that actually works. If this type of interface is insisted upon, please see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/naomik/e222280caaf2019bde1f) for a more functional implementation. I've attached some other notes there. ^.^

Comment: i do not insit of the interface, hence i changed it to just one inital function and the return function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77752/discussion-between-rookie-and-naomik).

Comment: nice, you could also write the same function this way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65537611/4099454

Answer (score 1):

Function composition has already been detailed in other answers, mostly https://stackoverflow.com/a/30198265/4099454, so my 2 cents are straight onto answering your latest question:

> If the para is a function, it "combines" the function into itself, and if not it will return the final result. Thanks!

```js
const chain = (g, f = x => x) => 
  typeof g === 'function'
  ? (y) => chain(y, (x) => g(f(x)))
  : f(g);

// ====

const triple = x => x * 3;
const inc = x => x + 1;
const isZero = x => x === 0;

console.log(
  chain(inc)(triple)(isZero)(-1),
);
```

Comment: Nice work matching the OP's exact proposal. Beware type-checking inputs and giving special behaviour to functions means `chain` can no longer accept functionals as arguments. For example, often times we need to compute a function, such as a thunk or a continuation, and pass it as an argument to another function. In this setup, `chain` would hazardously compose the functional instead of passing it as an argument to the composition.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to build a complex Functionality by Composing Simple Functions in JavaScript.In a sense, the composition is the nesting of functions, passing the result of one in as the input into the next. But rather than creating an indecipherable amount of nesting, we'll create a higher-order function, compose(), that takes all of the functions we want to combine, and returns us a new function to use in our app.

```
function triple(x) {
  return x * 3;
}
function plusOne(x) {
  return x + 1;
}
function isZero(x) {
  return x === 0;
}

const compose = (...fns) => x =>
  fns.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    return cur(acc);
  }, x);

const withCompose = compose(triple, triple, isZero);
console.log(withCompose(1));
```

Comment: compose should be right to left, you wrote a pipe instead

Answer (score -1):

You can simply call the function on the return values themselves, for example:

```
plusOne(triple(triple(1))) // 10
isZero(triple(plusOne(-1))) // true
```

Comment: Could you please explain why my answer is so poor down-voter?

Comment: I didn't down-vote your post, but it doesn't really answer the question. The OP wants to programmatically build a "chain" or "pipeline" of functions. It is called [function composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition) and javascript doesn't have a built-in function for it. Your answer is likely telling the OP something he/she already knows how to do.

Comment: @naomik I would say it depends on what the OP means as "combines", and if the OP already knew that solution I would imagine they would comment that. I'm simply stating you can get the correct results by performing `f(g(x))` other than making a functions that is `F = f(g(x))`, assuming that the OP may be a beginner and perhaps might not know that. It does (in a way) combine the functions and does indeed produces the correct results the OP wanted, so I don't see how it's not an answer.

Comment: @naomik Although I could of just misunderstood the question, seems clear your answer is what the OP was looking for.