# What do multiple arrow functions mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I have been reading a bunch of [React](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(web_framework)) code and I see stuff like this that I don't understand:

```
handleChange = field => e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  /// Do something here
}
```

Comment: Just for fun, [Kyle Simpson](http://stackoverflow.com/users/228852/kyle-simpson) put all the decision paths for arrows into [this flow chart](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20&%20beyond/fig1.png). Source: [His comment](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/06/es6-in-depth-arrow-functions/comment-page-1/#comment-17743) on a Mozilla Hacks blog post entitled [ES6 In Depth: Arrow functions](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/06/es6-in-depth-arrow-functions)

Comment: The URL for the arrow functions flow chart is now broken because there's a new edition of the book. Working URL is at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/1st-ed/es6%20%26%20beyond/fig1.png

Answer (score 1277):

**That is a [curried function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying)**

First, examine this function with two parameters …

```
const add = (x, y) => x + y
add(2, 3) //=> 5
```

Here it is again in curried form …

```
const add = x => y => x + y
```

Here is the same<sup>1</sup> code without arrow functions …

```
const add = function (x) {
  return function (y) {
    return x + y
  }
}
```

---

**Focus on `return`**

It might help to visualize it another way. We know that arrow functions work like this – let's pay particular attention to the **return value**.

```
const f = someParam => returnValue
```

So our `add` function returns a *function* – we can use parentheses for added clarity. The **bolded** text is the return value of our function `add`

```
const add = x => (y => x + y)
```

In other words `add` of some number returns a function

```
add(2) // returns (y => 2 + y)
```

---

**Calling curried functions**

So in order to use our curried function, we have to call it a bit differently …

```
add(2)(3)  // returns 5
```

This is because the first (outer) function call returns a second (inner) function. Only after we call the second function do we actually get the result. This is more evident if we separate the calls on two lines …

```
const add2 = add(2) // returns function(y) { return 2 + y }
add2(3)             // returns 5
```

---

**Applying our new understanding to your code**

> related: [*”What’s the difference between binding, partial application, and currying?”*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41962192/633183)

OK, now that we understand how that works, let's look at your code

```
handleChange = field => e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  /// Do something here
}
```

We'll start by representing it without using arrow functions …

```
handleChange = function(field) {
  return function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    // Do something here
    // return ...
  };
};
```

However, because arrow functions lexically bind `this`, it would *actually* look more like this …

```
handleChange = function(field) {
  return function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    // Do something here
    // return ...
  }.bind(this)
}.bind(this)
```

Maybe now we can see what this is doing more clearly. The `handleChange` function is creating a function for a specified `field`. This is a handy React technique because you're required to setup your own listeners on each input in order to update your applications state. By using the `handleChange` function, we can eliminate all the duplicated code that would result in setting up `change` listeners for each field. Cool!

<sup>1</sup> Here I did not have to lexically bind `this` because the original `add` function does not use any context, so it is not important to preserve it in this case.

---

**Even more arrows**

More than two arrow functions can be sequenced, if necessary -

```js
const three = a => b => c =>
  a + b + c

const four = a => b => c => d =>
  a + b + c + d

three (1) (2) (3) // 6

four (1) (2) (3) (4) // 10
```

Curried functions are capable of surprising things. Below we see `$` defined as a curried function with two parameters, yet at the call site, it appears as though we can supply any number of arguments. Currying is the abstraction of [arity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity) -

```js
const $ = x => k =>
  $ (k (x))
  
const add = x => y =>
  x + y

const mult = x => y =>
  x * y
  
$ (1)           // 1
  (add (2))     // + 2 = 3
  (mult (6))    // * 6 = 18
  (console.log) // 18
  
$ (7)            // 7
  (add (1))      // + 1 = 8
  (mult (8))     // * 8 = 64
  (mult (2))     // * 2 = 128
  (mult (2))     // * 2 = 256
  (console.log)  // 256
```

**Partial application**

Partial application is a related concept. It allows us to partially apply functions, similar to currying, except the function does not have to be defined in curried form -

```js
const partial = (f, ...a) => (...b) =>
  f (...a, ...b)

const add3 = (x, y, z) =>
  x + y + z

partial (add3) (1, 2, 3)   // 6

partial (add3, 1) (2, 3)   // 6

partial (add3, 1, 2) (3)   // 6

partial (add3, 1, 2, 3) () // 6

partial (add3, 1, 1, 1, 1) (1, 1, 1, 1, 1) // 3
```

Here's a working demo of `partial` you can play with in your own browser -

```js
const partial = (f, ...a) => (...b) =>
  f (...a, ...b)
  
const preventDefault = (f, event) =>
  ( event .preventDefault ()
  , f (event)
  )
  
const logKeypress = event =>
  console .log (event.which)
  
document
  .querySelector ('input[name=foo]')
  .addEventListener ('keydown', partial (preventDefault, logKeypress))
```

```html
<input name="foo" placeholder="type here to see ascii codes" size="50">
```

Comment: This is outstanding! How often does someone actually assign the '$' though? Or is it an alias for this in react? Forgive my ignorance on the last, just curious because I don't see a symbol getting an assignment too often in other languages.

Comment: @Caperneoignis `$` was used to demo the concept, but you could name it whatever you want. Coincidentally but completely unrelated, `$` _has_ been used in popular libraries like jQuery, where `$` is sort of the global entry point to the entire library of functions. I think it's been used in others too. Another you'll see is `_`, popularized in libraries like underscore and lodash. No one symbol is more meaningful than another; _you_ assign the meaning for _your_ program. It's simply valid JavaScript :D

Comment: I know I'm really late to this, but can you explain the `const $ = x => k =>
  $ (k (x))` you have going on there? I'm having a hard time wrapping my mind around what is actually happening.

Comment: @Blake You can gain a better understanding of `$` by looking at how it is used. If you're asking about the implementation itself, `$` is a function which receives a value `x` and returns a new function `k => ...`. Looking at the body of the returned function, we see `k (x)` so we know `k` must  also be a function, and whatever the result of `k (x)` is gets put back in to `$ (...)`, which we know returns another `k => ...`, and on it goes... If you're still getting stuck, let me know.

Comment: while this answer explained how it works and what patterns there are with this technique. I feel there isn't anything specific on why this is actually a better solution in any scenario. In what situation, `abc(1,2,3)` is less than ideal than `abc(1)(2)(3)`. It's harder to reason about the logic of code and it's hard to read function abc and it's harder to read the function call. Before you only needed to know what abc does, now you are not sure what unnamed functions abc is returning do, and twice at that.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer sorry but the advantages of functional style cannot be summarised in a short post, especially talking about an imaginary function, `abc`, which has no meaning. One thing I will say is that currying allows for different arguments to be supplied at various call sites along your program's timeline. This is useful in cases where all arguments are not ready at the same time/place. Benefits of learning alternative programming styles are vast and numerous. If you are curious why functional languages commonly use these techniques, you will have to start studying to see for yourself!

Comment: The convention in JS is to pass the data and appending to it, until it's where it's needed instead of closuring it into multiple functions and then passing along those functions. For example, in react "props drilling", middleware modifying the request object in expressjs.

Comment: @Thankyou so there is no good real world example? `.addEventListener ('keydown', partial (preventDefault, logKeypress))` you can write as `addEventlistener("keydown", (ev) => {preventDefault(ev); logKeypress(ev)}` _wayyyy_ better readable. And the calculator is super hard to read too. Seems like an anti pattern to stay away from

Comment: @Thankyou fantastic answer. I have been waiting dehlivery of Wadler and Bird's functional programming book for a while. In the mean time can you help me understand why the recursive call to $ does not create an infinite loop. When I try to write out the steps the program makes I can't see how it would ever stop calling itself?

Comment: @lindsaymacvean I haven't read it but if you learn something cool, feel free to share! `$` does not infinite loop because it is curried with _two_ parameters and the recursive call only applies _one_ argument. So instead of immediately running, it returns a function waiting for the second argument. This is exactly what is happening in the beginning section labeled _Focus on return_. If you have any other questions I'm happy to help :D

Comment: Thank you I see that now. It took me a while to see that it is a 'story that never ends' just functions returning functions, these are my notes:   
`$(1)` returns function k=>$(k(1))
`(add(2))`  'add' returns function y=>x+y with  x=2 so y=>2+y // 
so k(1) means y=1 so 2+1
which is passed as x back into $ which returns k=>$(k(3)) ... waiting for invocation //  
`(console.log);` k(3) is now console.log(3) //
passed back into $ which returns k=>$(k(console.log)) ... waiting for invocation //
Not many functions know what to do when passed console.log so tends to error if invoked

Comment: @Toskan I realize this is now kind of old, but here goes. Honestly, with the two lines of code you just laid beside each other, I think the curried version is quite a bit easier to read. There are various other examples of this kind of thing, like fluent, return-by-argument, RxJS streaming operator style, promise vs async/await, etc. Different ways of structuring code to promote clarity in one area. What counts as 'clean' is often a product of experience, familiarity, and what the environment gives you for free.

Comment: @MarkMcKenna "return by argument" never heard. chat gpt doesnt know what it is either. Everything else: not sure what is your point. Everything is relative. And people like to be relativity kings now a days. in the specific example you prefer one or the other?

Answer (score 111):

**Briefly**

It is a function that returns another function written in a short way.

```js
const handleChange = field => e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  // Do something here
}

// is equal to 
function handleChange(field) {
  return function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    // Do something here
  }
}
```

**Motivation**

This technique can be utilized in a scenario where we have a callback function with fixed parameters, but we need to pass additional variables while avoiding global variables.

For instance, we have a button that has an `onClick` callback, and we want to pass a variable, such as `id`, but `onClick` accepts a single argument, `event`, making it impossible to pass `id` along with `event`.

```js
const handleClick = (event, id) {
  event.preventDefault()
  // Dispatch some delete action by passing record `id`
}
```

It is not going to work.

Here as a solution, we write a function that returns another function with `id` in its variables scope without using any global variables:

```js
const handleClick = id => event {
  event.preventDefault()
  // Dispatch some delete action by passing record `id`
}

const Confirm = props => (
  <div>
    <h1>Are you sure to delete?</h1>
    <button onClick={handleClick(props.id)}>
      Delete
    </button>
  </div
)
```

**Function composition**

Multiple arrow functions also are called "curried functions" and are used for function compositions.

```js
import {compose} from 'redux'
import {store} from './store.js'

const pickSelectedUser = props => {
  const {selectedName, users} = props
  const foundUser = users.find(user => user.name === selectedName)
  
  return foundUser.id
}

const deleteUser = userId => event => {
  event.preventDefault()
  store.dispatch({
    type: `DELETE_USER`,
    userId,
  })
}

// The compose function creates a new function that accepts a parameter.
// The parameter will be passed throw the functions from down to top.
// Each function will change the value and pass it to the next function
// By changing value it was not meant a mutation
const handleClick = compose(
  deleteUser,
  pickSelectedUser,
)

const Confirm = props => (
  <div>
    <h1>Are you sure to delete?</h1>
    <button onClick={handleClick(props)}>
      Delete
    </button>
  </div
)
```

Comment: so how is this superior to `const handleClick = (ev, id) => {ev.preventDefault(); //do somth with id}` and doing `onClick="(ev) => handleClick(ev, id);"` <--- this is _way_ more readable. In your version, it is not obvious that there is even something happening with `event`

Comment: @Toskan - yes you are right, the version `handleClick(ev, id)` is more obvious at some point, but it is not composable. Check this snippet: https://gist.github.com/sultan99/13ef56b4089789a8d115869ee2c5ec47 and you will find that curried function are good for function composition which is very important part of functional programming.

Answer (score 85):

A general tip: If you get confused by any of new JavaScript syntax and how it will compile, you can check [Babel](https://babeljs.io/). For example, copying your code in Babel and selecting the ES 2015 preset will give an output like this

```
handleChange = function handleChange(field) {
  return function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Do something here
  };
};
```

[image: Babel]

Answer (score 68):

Understanding the [available syntaxes of arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Syntax) will give you an understanding of what behaviour they are introducing when 'chained' like in the examples you provided.

When an arrow function is written without block braces, with or without multiple parameters, the expression that constitutes the function's body is *implicitly* returned. In your example, that expression is another arrow function.

```
No arrow funcs              Implicitly return `e=>{…}`    Explicitly return `e=>{…}` 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function (field) {         |  field => e => {            |  field => {
  return function (e) {    |                             |    return e => {
      e.preventDefault()   |    e.preventDefault()       |      e.preventDefault()
  }                        |                             |    }
}                          |  }                          |  }
```

Another advantage of writing anonymous functions using the arrow syntax is that they are bound lexically to the scope in which they are defined. From ['Arrow functions' on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

> An **arrow function expression** has a shorter syntax compared to [function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) and lexically binds the [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) value. Arrow functions are always [anonymous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name).

This is particularly pertinent in your example considering that it is taken from a [reactjs](/questions/tagged/reactjs) application. As as pointed out by @naomik, in React you often access a [component's member functions](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html) using `this`. For example:

```
Unbound                     Explicitly bound            Implicitly bound 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function (field) {         |  function (field) {       |  field => e => {
  return function (e) {    |    return function (e) {  |    
    this.setState(...)     |      this.setState(...)   |    this.setState(...)
  }                        |    }.bind(this)           |    
}                          |  }.bind(this)             |  }
```

Answer (score 55):

Think of it like this, every time you see a arrow, you replace it with `function`.
`function parameters` are defined before the arrow.
So in your example:

```
field => // function(field){}
e => { e.preventDefault(); } // function(e){e.preventDefault();}
```

and then together:

```
function (field) { 
    return function (e) { 
        e.preventDefault(); 
    };
}
```

[From the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Syntax):

```
// Basic syntax:
(param1, param2, paramN) => { statements }
(param1, param2, paramN) => expression
   // equivalent to:  => { return expression; }

// Parentheses are optional when there's only one argument:
singleParam => { statements }
singleParam => expression
```

Comment: Don't forget to mention the lexically bound `this`.

Answer (score 6):

It might be not totally related, but since the question mentioned react uses case (and I keep bumping into this SO thread): There is one important aspect of the double arrow function which is not explicitly mentioned here.
Only the 'first' arrow(function) gets named (and thus 'distinguishable' by the run-time), any following arrows are anonymous and from React point of view count as a 'new' object on every render.

Thus double arrow function will cause any PureComponent to rerender all the time.

**Example**

You have a parent component with a change handler as:

```
handleChange = task => event => { ... operations which uses both task and event... };
```

and with a render like:

`{
   tasks.map(task => <MyTask handleChange={this.handleChange(task)}/>
}`

handleChange then used on an input or click. And this all works and looks very nice. BUT it means that any change that will cause the parent to rerender (like a completely unrelated state change) will also re-render ALL of your MyTask as well even though they are PureComponents.

This can be alleviated many ways such as passing the 'outmost' arrow and the object you would feed it with or writing a custom shouldUpdate function or going back to basics such as writing named functions (and binding the this manually...)

Answer (score 2):

The example in your question is that of a `curried function` which makes use of `arrow function` and has an `implicit return` for the first argument.

Arrow function lexically bind this i.e they do not have their own `this` argument but take the `this` value from the enclosing scope

An equivalent of the above code would be

```
const handleChange = (field) {
  return function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     /// Do something here
  }.bind(this);
}.bind(this);
```

One more thing to note about your example is that define `handleChange` as a const or a function. Probably you are using it as part of a class method and it uses a `class fields syntax`

so instead of binding the outer function directly, you would bind it in the class constructor

```
class Something{
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }
    handleChange(field) {
        return function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Another thing to note in the example is the difference between implicit and explicit return.

```
const abc = (field) => field * 2;
```

Above is an example of implicit return ie. it takes the value field as argument and returns the result `field*2` which explicitly specifying the function to return

For an explicit return you would explicitly tell the method to return the value

```
const abc = () => { return field*2; }
```

Another thing to note about arrow functions is that they do not have their own `arguments` but inherit that from the parents scope as well.

For example if you just define an arrow function like

```
const handleChange = () => {
   console.log(arguments) // would give an error on running since arguments in undefined
}
```

As an alternative arrow functions provide the rest parameters that you can use

```
const handleChange = (...args) => {
   console.log(args);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Multiple arrow functions in JavaScript represent a chaining of functions where the output of one function is taken as the input of the next function, and so on. for example:

```js
const add = (x) => (y) => x + y;
const multiply = (x) => (y) => x * y;

const result = add(2)(3); // 5
const finalResult = multiply(result)(4); // 20
```

In the example above, `add` and `multiply` are arrow functions that take a single parameter and return another arrow function. The first arrow function takes a number `x` and returns another arrow function which takes another number `y` and returns the sum of `x` and `y`. The second arrow function takes a number `x` and returns another arrow function which takes another number `y` and returns the product of `x` and `y`.

To use the functions, you can chain them together by calling one function with its parameter and then immediately calling the returned function with the next parameter. In the example above, `result` is the output of `add(2)(3)` which is `5`, and `finalResult` is the output of `multiply(result)(4)` which is `20`.

Comment: nice. just out of curiosity, did you get any of this from chatgpt?