# What is double arrow function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, arrow-functions

What is "let x= something1 => something2 => something3" ?

I have this code and I'm failing to understand what does it do.

```
const myReducers = {person, hoursWorked};
const combineReducers = reducers => (state = {}, action) => {
  return Object.keys(reducers).reduce((nextState, key) => {
    nextState[key] = reducers[key](state[key], action);
    return nextState;
  }, {});
};
```

The full code incase you need:

```
//Redux-Style Reducer
const person = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case 'ADD_INFO':
      return Object.assign({}, state, action.payload)
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const infoAction = {type: 'ADD_INFO', payload: {name: 'Brian', framework: 'Angular'}}
const anotherPersonInfo = person(undefined, infoAction);
console.log('***REDUX STYLE PERSON***: ', anotherPersonInfo);

//Add another reducer
const hoursWorked = (state = 0, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case 'ADD_HOUR':
      return state + 1;
    case 'SUBTRACT_HOUR':
      return state - 1;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
//Combine Reducers Refresher

****HERE****
****HERE****
****HERE****

const myReducers = {person, hoursWorked};
const combineReducers = reducers => (state = {}, action) => {
  return Object.keys(reducers).reduce((nextState, key) => {
    nextState[key] = reducers[key](state[key], action);
    return nextState;
  }, {});
};


****
****


/*
This gets us most of the way there, but really want we want is for the value of firstState and secondState to accumulate
as actions are dispatched over time. Luckily, RxJS offers the perfect operator for this scenario., to be discussed in next lesson.
*/
const rootReducer = combineReducers(myReducers);
const firstState = rootReducer(undefined, {type: 'ADD_INFO', payload: {name: 'Brian'}});
const secondState = rootReducer({hoursWorked: 10, person: {name: 'Joe'}}, {type: 'ADD_HOUR'});
console.log('***FIRST STATE***:', firstState);
console.log('***SECOND STATE***:', secondState);
```

From: https://gist.github.com/btroncone/a6e4347326749f938510

Comment: It's just a bunch of functions passed as arguments. The top-level function, I assume, is at some point called with your map of reducers.

Comment: Can you send a link that explain this or explain better what do you mean?

Comment: Explain what specifically? Arrow functions are explained in ES2015 docs/tutorials. `reduce` has normal function docs. Are you asking about the Redux part?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do multiple arrow functions mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32782922/what-do-multiple-arrow-functions-mean-in-javascript)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

let x= something1 => something2 => something3 is almost same as the following:

```js
let x = function (something) {
  return function (something2) {
    return something3
  }
}
```

The only difference is, arrows have lexical binding of `this`, i.e. binding in compile time.

Comment: does x = something3 in the end of the proccess?

Comment: No. `x` is now a function expression. if you call let abc = x(). Then abc will we equal to something3

Comment: Okay I got it. Thanks for your answer mate!

Comment: Have a fun time with redux :)

Answer (score 5):

An arrow function is

```
someParameters => someExpression
```

So, what is

```
someParameters => someThing => someThingElse
```

???

Well, by simple stupid "pattern matching", it's an arrow function, whose body (`someExpression`) is

```
someThing => someThingElse
```

In other words, it's

```
someParameters => someOtherParameters => someExpression
```

There's nothing special about this. Functions are objects, they can be returned from functions, no matter if those functions are written using arrows or the `function` keyword.

The only thing you really need to know to read this properly is that the arrow is right-associative, IOW that

```
a => b => c === a => (b => c)
```

---

Note: An arrow function can also have a body consisting of statements as well as a single expression. I was specifically referring to the form the OP is confused about.

Comment: Thanks for your time and great answer but I choosed the other one becouse, for some reason it was more clear to me. thanks agian.

Comment: That's okay, my answer assumes that one already knows what an arrow function is, Aakash's explains it without arrow functions at all.