# java-script arrow function returns (x++,x)

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

i don't know how the code:`const countFrom = x => () => (x++, x);` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42439070/11841240),
works:

```js
const countFrom = x => () => (x++, x);
let a = countFrom(1)

console.log('output:', a()) // output: 2
console.log('output:', a()) // output: 3
console.log('output:', a()) // output: 4
console.log('output:', a()) // output: 5
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100%!important; top: 0;}
```

Comment: This is just comma operator. It evaluates each of its operands from left to right and returns the value of the last operand.

Comment: `countFrom` receives `x` as an argument and then returns a closure that when called increments x and returns its value. `(x++, x)` is just shorthand for `{ x++; return x; }`

Comment: Study concept of closures.

Comment: @Aleksey best answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x` is a variable inside the outer (`x =>`) function, therefore all inner functions (`() => (x++, x)`) share the same variable. `x++` post increments that variable whenever the inner function executes. The comma operator (`..., x`) evaluates to the last comma seperated expression, `x` in this case.

It is maybe easier to understand without the comma operator:

```
 const counter = x => () => x = x + 1;
```

Comment: I wonder why nobody has mentioned `const counter = x => () => ++x;` yet…

Comment: @bergi yeah, thought that `x = x + 1` was easier to understand, would've chosen `++x` if I'd write it for myself though

Comment: @Bergi yes that is better

Answer (score 1):

```js
//const countFrom = x => () => (x++, x);
//Lets refactor the code a bit:

function countFrom(x){
return function(){
x++;
return x;
}
}

let a = countFrom(1)
//now a is the returned function at line 5, and x is stored as a local variable.
console.log('output:', a()) // output: 2 you call the function at line 5 so it adds 1 to x and returns it
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100%!important; top: 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple if you understand some aspects:

1. You have got two functions in the first line, not only one: the first one returns the second function `()=> (x++,x)` (see what `closure` is)
2. Inside round bracket you see comma operator and the result of the statement is the last operand of the comma operator (here x),
3. The round bracket works like `return x`, that is `=> (x)` is the same as `=> return x`