# how does multiple lambda function work?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have found a script example, in it there is a line of code that looks something like this:

```
fn = (arg1) => (arg2) => {
    //do something with arg1 and arg2
}
```

I am wondering exactly what is happening here, and how would it look as a "normal" function?

Comment: related: [What do multiple arrow functions mean in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32782922/what-do-multiple-arrow-functions-mean-in-javascript)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
fn = (arg1) => (arg2) => {
    //do something with arg1 and arg2
}
```

`fn` is a name for the first anon function 
its basically a function that returns another function

it translated roughly to

```
var fn = function(arg1){
  return function(arg2){
    ... // do something 
  }
}
```

noting that the `this` value will differ because it is an arrow function .

Comment: tx, but what is it that happens with `this`?

Comment: arrow function does not bind its own this  unlike regular functions .

Comment: so, in the first example `this`would refer to fn, whereas `this`inside the return function in the second example will refer to the return function itself?

Comment: regular functions in javascript introduce their own this depending on how they are called , but arrow functions don't , if you call this inside an arrow function it will treat it as a regular variable and go look for in outer scope .

Comment: http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_arrow-functions.html

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 6):

It looks like two nested function, where the outer function returns the inner function with a closure over `arg1`.

```
var fn = function (arg1) {
        return function (arg2) {
            //do something with arg1 and arg2
        };
    };
```

```js
var fn = function (arg1) {
        return function (arg2) {
            return arg1 + arg2;
        };
    };


var add4 = fn(4),
    add20 = fn(20);

console.log(add4(5));  //  9
console.log(add20(5)); // 25
```

[Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) and does not bind its own [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments), [super](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super), or [new.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target). These function expressions are best suited for non-method functions, and they cannot be used as constructors.

Comment: nice example, but the other answer mentions some difference in `this`, do you know what it means?

Comment: @Winter Out of scope for this question / comments. Give [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch) a read.

Answer (score -1):

I cannot add comments so I write this as an answer. Your example is also known as **currying** a concept that allows you to pass in a subset of arguments to a function and get a function back that’s waiting for the rest of the arguments.

Comment: If you don't have enough rep to add comments, you need to gain rep by adding *valid answers*. In fact, if you just added some example code to answer the OP's question this would be a perfectly good answer

Comment: exactly  that is currying .

Comment: @CodingIntrigue Yea I've figured that out, but what I dont understand is why I get -1 when I give valid answers. Its wierd? When do you normally use let fn = (arg1) => (arg2)? If you know about the currying concept, it is easier for you to understand the example code, isnt it?

Comment: People feel that this doesn't quite answer the question. The question is `I am wondering exactly what is happening here, and how would it look as a "normal" function?` If you asked me that and I said `it's also known as currying` I'm pretty sure you'd give me a quizical look :) It's certainly correct, it's just it is a footnote to the actual answer - you should look at the upvoted answers here so see how they differ.

Comment: CodingIntrigue yes and that is exactly why I wrote 'I cannot add comments...', because my answer is a sidenote, so people who is reading this question gets to know about the concept and can understand the 'what is happening here' part in the question.

Comment: That's what comments are for. I know it's frustrating, but if the only thing you have to add is a comment you just need to hold off at first & only add valid answers. Once you get a few of those (it's not too many), then you can add as many comments as needed :)

Comment: true, it is really frustrating, thanks =) I will work on my rep.

Comment: "_currying a concept that allows you to pass in a subset of arguments to a function and get a function back that’s waiting for the rest of the arguments._" I'd upvote, but your definition of currying is wrong. What you describe is actually partial application.