# Passing parameters to an event function in a Stateless Functional Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a playlist that I'm trying to bind a keyDown to.. the problem is that I cannot use a typical React.Component as I am using a library (https://github.com/clauderic/react-sortable-hoc) that requires me to use a functional Stateless Component (SortableContainer).  So I have no way to access props or a state even. I've tried to pass data as a parameter with nothing working..

This works, but I need to pass data to handleKeyDown somehow.. in particular I really want to pass "props" into handleKeyDown somehow

```
function handleKeyDown(e) {
  // **** I need some way to access outside data in here some how..
  //      whether it's passed as a parameter or any other way
  console.log(e.keyCode);
}

const PlaylistPages = SortableContainer(( props ) => {
  return (
    <div className="playlist-sortable" onKeyDown={handleKeyDown} tabIndex="0">
    // etc
  );
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), and pass the props and event object inside `handleKeyDown` function.

Write it like this:

```
onKeyDown = { e => handleKeyDown(props, e)}

handleKeyDown(props, e){
   console.log(e.target, props);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think better way of writing would be:

```
onClick={clickHandler(passedData)}

clickHandler= (passedData) => (e) => {
  console.log(e)
  console.log(passedData)
}
```

Arrow functions would cause unnecessary re-renders.

Comment: Could you clarify a bit more about this solution? it does work, but it's not straight forward to understand this behavior.

Comment: It is infact curry function. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32787782/7845230) link for better clarification.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass your parameters to a higher order function which will do the trick for you

```
function handleKeyDown(passedData) {
    return e => {
        console.log(passedData); // hello
        console.log(e.keyCode);
    }
}

const PlaylistPages = SortableContainer(( props ) => {
  const dataToPass = 'hello'
  return (
    <div className="playlist-sortable" onKeyDown={handleKeyDown(dataToPass)} tabIndex="0">
    // etc
  );
}
```

Comment: is an antipattern? @ShubhamKhatri

Comment: sorry didn't see  that you are returning a function but what mayank said in comments is a shorthand