# es6 arrow function explanation

Tags: ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

```
{
  getter: {
    myThing: state => lookup => {
      return state.things[lookup];
    },
    myThings: state => {
      return state.things;
    }
  }
}
```

Given the above 2 functions, are the following equivalent?

```
{
  getter: {
    myThing: (state, lookup) => {
      return state.things[lookup];
    },
    myThings: (state) => {
      return state.things;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does that 2 arrow expression work without error?

Comment: @rjustin - Yes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32782922/what-do-multiple-arrow-functions-mean-in-javascript

Comment: The myThing method above will be called as a composite function if written that way which would be `myThing(state)(lookup)`, so it's not the same with the one below it.

Answer (score 2):

`(state) => {` … `}` and `state => {` … `}` are equivalent, since parentheses are optional around single arguments in arrow functions.

`state => lookup => {` … `}` and `(state, lookup) => {` … `}` are **not** equivalent.

The first expression is a function that takes *one* argument and returns *another function* that also takes *one* argument, whereas the second expression is a function that takes *two* arguments.

An expression such as `a => b => {return a + b;}` is an example of currying. You can use both variants like this:

```
const add = a => b => (a + b);
add(2)(3); // 5
add(2); // function add/<() // This refers to the `b => (a + b)` part
add(2, 3); // function add/<() // Like above, because the second argument is ignored

const add2 = (a, b) => (a + b);
add2(2)(3); // TypeError: add2(...) is not a function
add2(2); // NaN // b isn’t provided
add2(2, 3); // 5
```

`(state) => (lookup) => {` … `}` would be equivalent to the first expression.

---

NB: `(state) => (lookup) => {` … `}` requires an explicit `return` to return the value; omitting the curly brackets `{` … `}` doesn’t.

Comment: maybe you add that curly brackets require an expicit return statement for returning a value, different from `undefined`.