# Javascript function inside functions

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, functional-programming

Today I observed the following syntax (simplified example):

```js
const test = fn => () => console.log(fn) 
test('foo')();
```

Having a hard time wrapping my head around this but it still remains vague to me. What exactly happens step by step?

Comment: So you understand the syntax of the arrow functions? And you could produce the code for `test` with `function`?

Comment: yes, they are declaring other functions

Comment: What in particular is vague? Would it help to introduce a temporary variable for the `test('foo')` part of the expression?

Comment: `test` references an arrow function that when called returns another arrow function. `'foo'` is being passed in as an argument to `test` which only has one parameter named `fn` and that is probably not the best name for a variable holding a string and could be contributing to your confusion.

Comment: Did you have a look at [What do multiple arrow functions mean in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32782922/1048572)

Comment: Got it now after rewriting, sorry kind of bad question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's rewrite this in a way which maybe more understandable for you

```js
const test = function(fn){

  return function (){
  
   console.log(fn);
   
  }

} 
test('foo')();
```

Do you understand it now? If yes this is same as your example just uses normal function instead of arrow functions.

You also need to know what a closure is to understand this.

Answer (score 2):

As the answers already mentioned you are creating a closure.

In my answer, I want to say **what it is a closure good for**:

Imagin you want to greet three persons and two of them are your frinds and one is your boss. You want to greet your frinds with *"Hi"* but your boss with *"Hello"*.

```
const greet = greetingWord => name =>
    `${greetingWord}, ${name}`

const greetFrind = greet('Hi')
const greetBoss = greet('Hello')
```

We create a function `greet` which takes one arguement an will return a new function with one argument too (`greet = greetingWord => name`). Once we implement it we can define a greeter for our frinds and for the boss.

```js
const greet = greetingWord => name =>
  `${greetingWord}, ${name}`

const greetFrind = greet('Hi')
const greetBoss = greet('Hello')

console.log(greetFrind('Paul'))
console.log(greetFrind('Julia'))
console.log(greetBoss('Mr. Paker'))
```

Answer (score 1):

So this is basic concept of closure in JavaScript. If you rewrite the code in ES5:

```
var test = function(fn){
  return function(){
    console.log(fn);
  };
}

test('foo')();
```

So the inner function has access to the argument that was passed into the outer function. So that's why you are getting `"foo"`

Comment: ES5 doesn't have `const`.

Comment: Yes you're totally right. I copied the code from the question and completely forgot about that. Thank you!