# How to write a custom function that was automated pass parameter like getters in Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I read an example about getters in Vuex. Getters function has 2 parameters but only need to pass 1 parameter. What actually happen ? How do i write a custom function that have the same ability.

Delcaration:

```
getters: {
  // ...
  getTodoById: (state) => (id) => {
    return state.todos.find(todo => todo.id === id)
  }
}
```

Using:

```
store.getters.getTodoById(2)
```

Comment: This question is a duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32782922/what-do-multiple-arrow-functions-mean-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do multiple arrow functions mean in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32782922/what-do-multiple-arrow-functions-mean-in-javascript)