# How to prevent function from repeating items into an array of objects in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a state array that looks similar to this

```js
this.state = {
  var: "",
  arr1: [],
  other: ["item1", "item2", "item3"]
}
```

In my `render()` I list out the contents of the "other" array, and next to it, a user can put any number, which would be their ranking (doesn't matter if repeated) of the items in the "other array as shown below

```html
<Row className="App">
  <ul>
    {this.state.other.map((item, index) =>
      <li key={index}>{item}<Input className="rankCols" type="number" id="ranking" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, item)} /></li>
    )}
  </ul>
</Row>
```

Then in a `handleChange` function, I store the user ranking in an array of objects along with the `pName`

```js
handleChange = (item, event) => {
  const value = event.target.value
  this.setState(prev => {
    const idx = prev.arr1.findIndex(obj => obj.pName === item)
    if (idx > -1) {
      return {
        arr1: [...prev.arr1.slice(0, idx), {
          pName: item,
          priority: value
        }, ...prev.arr1.slice(0, idx + 1)]
      }
    } else {
      return {
        arr1: prev.arr1.concat([{
          pName: item,
          priority: value
        }])
      }
    }

  });
}
```

Now the problem is that, instead of the `arr1` looking like

```js
arr1: [{
    pName: "item1",
    priority: "3"
  },
  {
    pName: "item2",
    priority: "1"
  },
  {
    pName: "item3",
    priority: "2"
  }
]
```

It repeats the some of the values so it looks more like

```js
arr1: [{
    pName: "item1",
    priority: "3"
  },
  {
    pName: "item2",
    priority: "1"
  },
  {
    pName: "item3",
    priority: "2"
  },
  {
    pName: "item1",
    priority: "3"
  },
  {
    pName: "item2",
    priority: "1"
  },
  {
    pName: "item3",
    priority: "2"
  }
]
```

So it gives me problems in the backend, because each item cannot exist more than once. How could I prevent them from repeating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not slicing array properly, in the second slice you're using `...prev.arr1.slice(0, idx + 1)` which should be `...prev.arr1.slice(idx + 1,)`

you need to change this

```
if(idx > -1) {
           return {
              arr1: [...prev.arr1.slice(0, idx), {pName: item, priority: value}, ...prev.arr1.slice(0, idx + 1)]
           }
      }
```

to this

```
if(idx > -1) {
           return {
              arr1: [...prev.arr1.slice(0, idx), {pName: item, priority: value}, ...prev.arr1.slice(idx + 1,)]
           }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue, as CodeManiac points out, is that you're calling `slice` with incorrect boundaries.

However, doing an immutable update on an array is something you'll need to repeat anywhere you have an array in `state`. Break this up into a separate function, `insert`, so you don't have to repeat yourself. It also helps isolate complexity and keep your handlers clean -

```
const insert = (a = [], pos = 0, v = null) =>
  pos === -1
    ? [ ...a, v ]
    : [ ...a.slice(0, pos), v, ...a.slice(pos + 1) ]
```

Then in your component -

```
handleChange = (pName, event) =>
{ const priority = event.target.value
  const arr1 = this.state.arr1
  const next =
    insert
      ( arr1
      , arr1.findIndex(o => o.pName === pName)
      , { pName, priority }
      )

  this.setState({ arr1: next })
}
```

---

You might also consider [currying your handler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32782922/633183) -

```
handlerChange = pName => event =>
{ // ...
}
```

So in your `render`, you can use it like this -

```
<Row className="App">
  <ul>
    {this.state.other.map((item, index) =>
      <li key={index}>{item}<Input className="rankCols" type="number" id="ranking" onChange={this.handleChange(item)} /></li>
    )}
  </ul>
</Row>
```

---

Below is a fully functioning demo -

```js
const insert = (a = [], pos = 0, v = null) =>
  pos === -1
    ? [ ...a, v ]
    : [ ...a.slice(0, pos), v, ...a.slice(pos + 1) ]

class Main extends React.Component {

  state =
    { priorities: [] 
    , items: ["a", "b", "c" ]
    }

  click = name => event =>
  { const priority = event.target.value
    const arr = this.state.priorities
    const next =
      insert
        ( arr
        , arr.findIndex(o => o.name === name)
        , { name, priority }
        )

    this.setState({ priorities: next })
  }

  getPriority = name =>
  { const empty = { priority: 0 }
    const p = this.state.priorities.find(p => p.name === name) || empty
    return JSON.stringify(p)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.state.items.map((name, key) =>
          <li key={key}>
            <span>{name}</span>
            <button value="1" onClick={this.click(name)}>1</button>
            <button value="2" onClick={this.click(name)}>2</button>
            <button value="3" onClick={this.click(name)}>3</button>
            <input disabled value={this.getPriority(name)} />
          </li>
        )}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.querySelector("main"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<main></main>
```