# React Beginner Question: Confusing Arrow Function Example

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, arrow-functions

I'm a React/ES6 beginner and I'm using this code I found to handle a checkbox inside a custom component being clicked (the custom component includes a material-ui CheckBox, hence the "checked" value). I'm planning on adding more fields to the custom component, such as a textbox that corresponds to the checkbox where the user can add more information about the box they checked.

Anyway, I'm a bit confused about what's going on in that first line. I was hoping one of you senior level devs could break it down for me so i can understand what's happening here.

Two things to note:

1. index console logs as an integer value (position in my mapped array)
2. checked is false by default but console logs as true (is it being
   toggled true somehow?)

   ```
   const onMediaDeliverableChange = index => ({ target: {checked} }) => {

   console.log('>> [form.js] (onMediaDeliverablesChange) index =  ',index);
   console.log('>> [form.js] (onMediaDeliverablesChange) target =  ',checked); }
   ```

Here's an example of code that I took this from, that is working.

```
const onCheckBoxChange = index => ({ target: { checked } }) => {
    const newValues = [...values];
    const value = values[index];
    newValues[index] = { ...value, checked };

    console.log('>> [form.js] (onCheckBoxChange) value = ',value, index);
    console.log('>> [form.js] (onCheckBoxChange) newValues[index] = ',newValues[index]);

    props.setDesignOrDigital(newValues);

  };
```

Comment: This is just a function definition. Can you show how it's used in its respective component?

Comment: This is a curried function. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32782922/what-do-multiple-arrow-functions-mean-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following:

```
const onCheckBoxChange = index => ({ target: { checked } }) => {
  // stuff
};
```

could also be written as:

```
const onCheckBoxChange = index => (event) => {
  const checked = event.target.checked;
  // stuff
};
```

`{ target: { checked } }` is an example of using [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) on a function argument. In this case, the argument would be an event.

The first part:

`index => another-function`

is, as svey mentioned in the comments, an example of a curried function. I assume onCheckBoxChange was used in a loop where the index of the checkbox being rendered was passed in which then returns a function that is an event handler for the change event. The `index` is then used to get/set the checked state for the respective checkboxes.

Comment: Thank you Ryan! I suspected it had to do with destructuring but I couldn't wrap my head around what was going on there. Your explanation was helpful, I think I got it now. Thanks!