# How to write Typescript interface with double arrow functions

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

What is the syntax to write a typescript interface using double arrow function es6?

Example JS:

```
const myFunction => (param1) => (param2) => {
...code
}
```

Example: TS:

```
const myFunc = (param1: number) => (param2: number) => {
  return param1 + param2
};
```

this interface is incorrect

```
interface myInterface {
   myFunc: (param1: number) => (param2: number) => number
}
```

the error is: `Parsing error: ';' expected`
so why? and what is the correct syntax?

Comment: that interface is correct, unless you wanted https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLYE8CS5rycgbwChlSAKABzijlQEYAuZEAV1QCNoBKJy62gExNWHbsgC8APmZtOUIgF8A3ESIATCAgA21FAgD2IAM5hkkE0wzZIsRBBXmwZAKxcXXIA

Comment: The interface looks correct according to what you provided for Example JS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do multiple arrow functions mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32782922/what-do-multiple-arrow-functions-mean-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the error is coming from your Javascript.

```
const myFunction => (param1) => (param2) => {
...code
}
```

That is not legal JS.  Did you mean:

```
const myFunction = (param1) => (param2) => {
...code
}
```

The rest compiles just fine for me:

```
interface MyInterface {
   myFunc: (param1: number) => (param2: number) => number
}

const Foo: MyInterface = {

  myFunc: (param1: number) => (param2: number) => {
    return param1 + param2
  }

}

class FooClass implements MyInterface {

  myFunc(param1: number) {
    return (param2: number) => {
      return param1 + param2;
    }
  }

}
```