# Can't write higher order components in Typescript: JSX Element type does not have any construct or call signatures

Tags: reactjs, typescript, higher-order-components

Yes, I realize this question has been asked, but none of the answers I found resolved this.  I am writing a simple higher order component in Typescript to verify authorization before rendering a component. So far it looks like this:

```
export function withAuth(Component: React.ComponentType) {

    if (!Component) return null;

    useEffect(() => {
        verifyToken().then(res => console.log(res))
    }, []);

    return (
        <Component/>
    )
}
```

I have a larger FunctionComponent called `EditorContainer` that I pass to the HOC and export from its own file: `export default withAuth(EditorContainer)`;

Which is imported as `import EditorContainer from "./modules/Editor/containers/EditorContainer";` and throws this error.

**I have tried:**

1. Passing the HOC a new instance of the component instead of its
   constructor.  This throws a different error.
2. Changing or removing all types.  The error remains.
3. Updating `react, react-dom, @types/react` and `@types/react-dom`.
4. Capitalizing withAuth as WithAuth (I'm running out of ideas here).
5. Removing the component from its original location (being rendered by a React Router route).  Makes no difference.

It seems like writing a higher order component in TypeScript is disallowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see my comment as to why your solution is working; however you can remove the extra function.

```js
export function withAuth(Component: React.ComponentType) {

    if (Component == null) { return () => null; }
    return () => {
        useEffect(() => {
            verifyToken().then(res => console.log(res))
        }, []);

        return (
            <Component/>
        )
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this by defining the HOC as a [curried function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32782922/what-do-multiple-arrow-functions-mean-in-javascript). :

```
export const withAuth = (Component: ComponentType<any>) => (props: any) => {

    const AuthWrapper: FunctionComponent = (props: any) => {
        const [auth, setAuth] = useState<any>(null);

        useEffect(() => {
            verifyToken().then(res => {
                console.log(res);
                setAuth(res);
            })
        }, []);

        if (!auth) return <Result
            status="403"
            title="403"
            subTitle="Sorry, you are not authorized to access this page."
            extra={<Link to="/"><Button type="primary">Back Home</Button></Link>}
        />;

        return (
            <Component {...props} authUser={auth}/>
        )
    }

    return <AuthWrapper {...props}/>;

};
```

Literally no idea why this works, so I guess the question's not really answered.  How should explicitly returning a function be any different from returning a FunctionComponent which... is a function? Especially after stripping the types, I'm not clear on what the difference is.

Comment: This works because an HOC's input is a component and the output needs to be a component.  this works now because you are returning a stateless function which is returning a hook. :) . The stateless function is a valid react component.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Maybe I'm being a bit thick, but regardless of whether or not the return value is a function, it's ultimately just returning a React element.  So if I set the return type of the HOC as a ReactElement, why will it accept an anonymous function that does nothing but return an element, but not a direct return of the element?

Comment: The HOC would not return a ReactElement.  The HOC would need to return a `ComponentClass<P>` or a `FunctionComponent<P>`.

In your original post, `withAuth` is not an HOC, it is a `FunctionType<P>` which returns a React Element.  `withAuth(EditorContainer)` should return a `ComponentType<R = {}>` to satisfy the contract with react that comes from `export default withAuth(EditorContainer)`.  Once you added the anonymous function as the return type of `withAuth`, now you have a valid `ComponentType<P = {}>`. The anonymous fn is a valid `ComponentType<R = {}>` because it returns a ReactElement.

Comment: I think I *almost* understand, but it's not because your answer is lacking.  Thanks!