# How to get parameter from parent scope into child scope?

Tags: javascript

Having two functions one wrapping the other, how to pass a parameter down correctly? At the moment the console logging does not work.

```js
const a = (v) => (v) => console.log(v);
a(2);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32782922/what-do-multiple-arrow-functions-mean-in-javascript

Comment: it doesn't work because you have 1 more `(v) =>`. Make it like this - `const a = (v) => console.log(v);` and it will work

Comment: `a(2)` will execute the *first* function and return *another* function - `(v) =>console.log(v);`. So you need to execute the result again. Note that the two `v` parameters shadow themselves, so you need `a(1)(2)` but it's irrelevant what `1` actually is or if it's passed in.

Comment: It's not clear whether or not you know that you need to invoke this with `a()(2)`, or if you're trying to do `(v) => () => console.log(v)` so that you can say `hi = a('hello'); hi(); hi(); hi();` and get `hello hello hello`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing a parameter in High order fn is easy as the value get set to `closure`

```js
const a = v => () => {console.log(v)};
a(2)()
```

No matter how deep you go, parameter passed to `fn` get set to `closure` space when a `fn` having a parameter `v` either returns a `fn` or executes a `fn` which uses that parameter `v`

```js
const a = v => () => () => () => {console.log(v)}
a(2)()()()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to work on two functions

```js
const a = (v) => (a = v) => console.log(a);

a(2)()
```

Answer (score 1):

What you did over there to define a lambda function within a function.
If you want it to work with `a(2)` you need to excecture the inner function (meaning to add `()` at the end), like this:

```js
const a = (v) => (() => console.log(v))();
a(2);
```

This `(() => console.log(v))` is a function, when you add `()` at the end it's actually activating that function, and that's why what you did, didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have two `v` variables, and the inner one is *shadowing* the outer one since they have the same name. Unless you rename the inner `v`, there's no way to access the outer `v` from inside that function.