# How can i get access to component fields - React JS

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I got little issue with my dropdown component that i imported from 'react-select', i am newbie at React so its pretty hard for me to solve this. i just want to get the selection of user from dropdown list, how can i do that?

for example this is the Dropdown component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

const techCompanies = [
  { label: "Button", value: 1 },
  { label: "CheckBox", value: 2 },
  { label: "Color", value: 3 },
  { label: "Date", value: 4 },
  { label: "Local Date time", value: 5 },
  { label: "Email", value: 6 },
  { label: "File", value: 7 },
  { label: "Hidden", value: 8 },
  { label: "Image", value: 9 },
  { label: "Month", value: 10 },
  { label: "Number", value: 11},
  { label: "Password", value: 12},
  { label: "Radio", value: 13},
  { label: "Range", value: 14},
  { label: "Reset", value: 15},
  { label: "Search", value: 16},
  { label: "Submit", value: 17},
  { label: "Telephone", value: 18},
  { label: "Text", value: 19},
  { label: "Time", value: 20},
  { label: "URL", value: 21},
  { label: "Week", value: 22},
];
class DropDown extends React.Component{
    render(){
    return(
  <div className="container">
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-md-4"></div>
      <div className="col-md-4">
        <Select 
      options={ techCompanies } />
      </div>
      <div className="col-md-4"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
}
}
export default DropDown
```

and now i want to use my dropdown at App.js and show in `<h1>{userSelect}</h1>` the user selection, i cant find anyway to use pros ans state so i got stuck here:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
    <div>
    <DropDown/>
    </div>

  );
}
}
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to provide a way for the dropdown to change state. react-select provides a method called `onChange` that fires off the selected element every time a new one is selected. In order to do this, you'll need to keep track of the currently selected user input in your app component, and you'll need to pass a function down to DropDown so App can change the state whenever a new dropdown element is selected. You can update your code to the following to achieve this:

```js
// DropDown.jsx
class DropDown extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-4" />
          <div className="col-md-4">
            <Select options={techCompanies} onChange={this.props.onChange} /> // add the onChange prop passed from app into Select's onChange API method
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-4" />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default DropDown;
```

```js
// App.jsx

import React, { Component } from "react";
import DropDown from "./DropDown";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends Component {
  // you'll need to keep track of the currently selected input
  state = {
    userSelected: ""
  };

  setSelected = selected => {
    console.log(selected) // ex: { label: "Button", value: 1 }
    this.setState({ userSelected: selected.label });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.selected}</h1>
        <DropDown onChange={this.setSelected} /> // pass your onChange handler
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @Keith has said, pass down a `prop` handler that updates the state of the parent (**App**) and executes it on selection change in the child(**DropDown**). `React-Select` returns an object on selection change so you would have to extract out the `label-value` pair.

I am using React Hooks here, because hooks are amazing :)

---

#### DropDown.js component

```js
import React from "react";
import Select from "react-select";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

const techCompanies = [
  { label: "Button", value: 1 },
  { label: "CheckBox", value: 2 },
  { label: "Color", value: 3 },
  { label: "Date", value: 4 },
  { label: "Local Date time", value: 5 },
  { label: "Email", value: 6 },
  { label: "File", value: 7 },
  { label: "Hidden", value: 8 },
  { label: "Image", value: 9 },
  { label: "Month", value: 10 },
  { label: "Number", value: 11 },
  { label: "Password", value: 12 },
  { label: "Radio", value: 13 },
  { label: "Range", value: 14 },
  { label: "Reset", value: 15 },
  { label: "Search", value: 16 },
  { label: "Submit", value: 17 },
  { label: "Telephone", value: 18 },
  { label: "Text", value: 19 },
  { label: "Time", value: 20 },
  { label: "URL", value: 21 },
  { label: "Week", value: 22 }
];

const DropDown = ({ handleSelectionChange }) => {
  // Handler to track changes on selection
  const handleChange = () => selectedValue => {
    handleSelectionChange(selectedValue); // 2. Note that the selectedValue is in the curried param.
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-4" />
        <div className="col-md-4">
          <Select
            options={techCompanies}
            onChange={handleChange()} // 1. make a call to the handler here
          />
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-4" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DropDown;
```

1. Call the child DropDown handler `handleChange()` when the selection changes. Don't forget the parentheses.
2. Capture the [curried](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32787782/3758602) value and pass it to the parent by calling the prop `handleSelectionChange`

---

#### App.js component

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

import DropDown from "./DropDown";

const App = () => {
  const [userSelect, setUserSelect] = useState({});

  const handleChange = selectedValue => {
    // 3. Finally Capture the value from the DropDown here and update the state
    setUserSelect(() => setUserSelect(selectedValue));
  };

  // 4. Extract out the value from the state
  const { label, value } = userSelect;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {userSelect.value && <h1>{`${value} : ${label}`}</h1>}
      <DropDown handleSelectionChange={handleChange} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

3. The `App's` `handleChange` function receives the value object from `DropDown` on `handleChange` via the `handleSelectionChange` prop and uses it to update its own state.
4. Note that React-Select stores the selected values as { label: value } pair, so you would need to extract the desired value to display in the UI.

Checkout the [Live Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-answer-46110)