# Confusion about multi-parameter multi-arrow functions in JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, arrow-functions

I'm currently working through a tutorial on React and I'm having trouble understanding the syntax of these arrow functions, particularly when there are multiple parameters. I'm coming from Python and am still learning JS so please keep that in mind.

With the following function:

```
// ADD LEAD
export const addLead = (lead) => (dispatch, getState) => {
    axios
        .post('/api/leads/', lead, tokenConfig(getState))
        .then(........)
}
```

Why do we need multiple arrows? Why is `lead` in one set of parenthesis and `dispatch` and `getState` in another set? Coming from Python this syntax is incredibly confusing and non-intuitive.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do multiple arrow functions mean in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32782922/what-do-multiple-arrow-functions-mean-in-javascript)

Comment: Nice one @keikai!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`addLead` is a function that returns a function. Here's the same thing using function body syntax instead of concise body syntax, which may be clearer:

```
export const addLead = (lead) => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        axios
            .post('/api/leads/', lead, tokenConfig(getState))
            .then(........)
    };
}
```

So you'd call `addLead` to get a function with `lead` bound to it:

```
const f = addLead("some lead");
```

...and then call that with `dispatch` and `state` as appropriate:

```
f("dispatch", "state");
```

---

Side note: It's a bit odd (without more context) that the function `addLead` returns doesn't return the result of calling `axios`. I would have expected it to be:

```
export const addLead = (lead) => (dispatch, getState) => 
    axios
        .post('/api/leads/', lead, tokenConfig(getState))
        .then(........);
```

which is:

```
export const addLead = (lead) => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        return axios
            .post('/api/leads/', lead, tokenConfig(getState))
            .then(........);
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It's closure function. Which means it takes a variable and returns a function that give you access to that variable.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Your code essentially translates to following

```js
export const addLead = function(lead) {
  return function(dispatch, getState) {
axios
  .post('/api/leads/', lead, tokenConfig(getState))
  .then()
  }
}
```