# Compose function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I try to get some details from the code below:

```js
const upperCase = str => str.toUpperCase();
const exclaim = str => `${str}!`;
const repeat = str => `${str} `.repeat(3);

const compose = (...fns) => x => fns.reduceRight((acc, fn) => fn(acc), x);

const withСompose = compose(
  repeat,
  exclaim,
  upperCase
);

console.log(withСompose("hello"));
```

Questions:

1. How `x` from `=> x =>`, go instead `x` from `fn(acc), x);`?
2. Why `const compose = (...fns) => x => fns.reduceRight((acc, fn) => fn(acc), x);` does not work in this way `const compose = (...fns) => fns.reduceRight((acc, fn) => fn(acc));`?

Comment: Replace the arrow functions with their _old-school_ `function()` versions. This might be easier to understand.

Comment: Very relevant: [What do multiple arrow functions mean in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32782922)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.2. because reduce right takes two arguments `reduceRight(reducer, initialValue)`
the initial value in your case is the x itself

```js
const upperCase = str => str.toUpperCase();
const exclaim = str => `${str}!`;
const repeat = str => `${str} `.repeat(3);
const reducer = (acc, fn) => fn(acc);
const compose = (...fns) => x => fns.reduceRight(reducer, x);

const withСompose = compose(
  repeat,
  exclaim,
  upperCase
);

console.log(withСompose("hello"));
```

hope now it's clear

Comment: [`.reduceRight()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight) has only one required parameter -> `reducer`. The `initialValue` is optional.

Comment: @Shandor Kostur, do i understand right, that writing this: `withСompose("hello")`, i create a curried function and `hello` in this case will go instead of `x` as initialValue?

Comment: @AskMen to be more concrete you've created partial application not curried function but yes you're right in this case hello is the initialValue of reduce right

Answer (score 1):

May help to figure out, result of `compose`:

```js
const withСompose = function fnUpperCase(str1) {
    const resultStrFn1 = str1.toUpperCase();

    return (function fnExclaim(str2) {
        const resultStrFn2 = `${str2}!`;

        return (function fnRepeat(str3) {
            return `${str3} `.repeat(3);
        })(resultStrFn2);
    })(resultStrFn1);
};

console.log(withСompose('hello'));
```

Comment: could you take  a look please, thanks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63345237/save-data-in-a-special-order-when-click-on-button