# Javascript binding Higher-order function with input onchange not working

Tags: javascript, html, dom, events

My goal is to call a function with a string argument, calling function will return a function which will receive the event object from html input object, and I want to use the string argument in the second function.

```js
const person = {
  name:'',
  age:''
};

const regForm = (field) => {
  console.log('field : ', field);

  return event => {
    person[field]=event.target.value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(person);
  }
};
```

```html
<input onchange="regForm('name')"/>
<input onchange="regForm('age')"/>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Every time `regForm` gets invoked it returns an anonymous arrow function expression. Nothin else will happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your `onchange` attribute currently has a string-based value and it is effectively `eval`d when the change event is fired. As @PeterSeliger comments, `regForm` simply returns a function.

`regForm` *could* return anything, and so the default change handler makes no assumptions about your answer. You maybe be expecting that the returned function would be called with the event, but instead the default handler simply discards the value.

One solution would be to use JavaScript's `onchange` *property*, instead of HTML's `onchange` *attribute* -

```js
const person = {
  name:'',
  age:''
}
  
const regForm = field => event =>
  person[field] = event.target.value

const form =
  document.forms.sample
  
form.name.onchange = regForm("name")
form.age.onchange = regForm("age")
form.onsubmit = event => {
  event.preventDefault()
  console.log("Submitted", JSON.stringify(person))
}
```

```html
<form id="sample">
  <input name="name" placeholder="enter your name" />
  <input name="age" placeholder="enter your age" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

---

And since you are familiar with event delegation, ie `event.target`, you can remove additional duplication. Looks like `regForm` just kinda disappeared! -

```js
const data =
  {}

const form =
  document.forms.sample

form.onchange = event =>
  data[event.target.name] = event.target.value
  
form.onsubmit = event => {
  event.preventDefault()
  console.log("Submitted", JSON.stringify(data))
}
```

```html
<form id="sample">
  <input name="name" placeholder="enter your name"><br>
  <input name="age" placeholder="enter your age"><br>
  <input name="foo" placeholder="enter your foo"><br>
  <input name="bar" placeholder="enter your bar"><br>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Output

```
Submitted {"name":"1","age":"2","foo":"3","bar":"4"}
```

---

Functions that take other functions as input and/or return other functions as output are called *higher-order functions*. There are a variety of terminologies and techniques for dealing with them. For related reading, see [*What do multiple arrow functions mean*?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32787782/633183)

```js
const preventDefault = f => event =>
  ( event.preventDefault()
  , f(event)
  )
  
const logKeypress = event =>
  console.log(event.which)
  
document
  .querySelector('input[name=foo]')
  .addEventListener('keydown', preventDefault(logKeypress))
```

```html
<input name="foo" placeholder="type here to see ascii codes" size="50">
```

Answer (score 0):

In oder to come close to what the OP might have wished to achieve, one should break down the code into  the state-change handling task(, maybe a render task) and the listener-initializing task ...

```js
const person = {
  name:'',
  age:''
};

function renderPersonStateChange(personReference, key, value) {
  personReference[key] = value;

  document.body.querySelector('#demo').textContent = JSON.stringify(personReference);
}
function handleTextInputStateChange(evt) {
  const elm = evt.currentTarget;
  const key = elm.name;

  renderPersonStateChange(person, key, elm.value);
}

// initialize event listeners
document.body.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(elm =>
  elm.addEventListener('change', handleTextInputStateChange, false)
);
```

```html
<input name='name' placeholder="enter person's name"/>
<input name='age' placeholder="enter person's age"/>
<p>
  <code>
    <pre id="demo">
    </pre>
  </code>
</p>
```

If one wishes to[`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the reference that's state should be changed, the above code then slightly alters (only for the change-handler and the event-initialization parts) towards ...

```js
const person = {
  name:'',
  age:''
};

function renderPersonStateChange(personReference, key, value) {
  personReference[key] = value;

  document.body.querySelector('#demo').textContent = JSON.stringify(personReference);
}
function handleStateChangeForBoundPerson(evt) {
  const personReference = this;

  const elm = evt.currentTarget;
  const key = elm.name;

  renderPersonStateChange(personReference, key, elm.value);
}

// initialize event listeners
document.body.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(elm =>
  elm.addEventListener('change', handleStateChangeForBoundPerson.bind(person), false)
);
```

```html
<input name='name' placeholder="enter person's name"/>
<input name='age' placeholder="enter person's age"/>
<p>
  <code>
    <pre id="demo">
    </pre>
  </code>
</p>
```