# Is there a shorter way to write this code, assign a value to a sub object?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working with nodeJs and I would like to assign a sub value to an object without to know if the «three» exist.

E.g : I would like to assign True to «global.proc.trackingMarketExport.started» without check if :

- proc exist in global
- trackingMarketExport exist in global.proc
- ....

Actually I'm writing this :

```
!global?.proc && ( global.proc = {})
!global.proc?.trackingMarketExport && ( global.proc.trackingMarketExport = { started: false })
```

For sample :

```
global?.proc?.trackingMarketExport?.started = true;
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: `chainable(global).proc.trackingMarketExport.started = false` [see my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67108890)

Comment: So did anything answer your question??

Comment: I didn't know the proxy function, nice to use. Thx ;)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Perhaps you're asking how to *ensure* that the target object exists and that its `started` property is set to `true`?

If that's the case you can use the [logical nullish assignment operator (`??=`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment):

```js
(((global ??= {}).proc ??= {}).trackingMarketExport ??= {}).started = true;
```

```js
let global = undefined;

(((global ??= {}).proc ??= {}).trackingMarketExport ??= {}).started = true;

console.log(global);
```

---

You can use this syntax to assign it to the target object (if it exists) or to an anonymous, ephemeral object that will be garbage collected (if it doesn't):

```js
(global?.proc?.trackingMarketExport ?? {}).started = true;
```

Here's a code snippet you can re-run repeatedly to see randomized results. Note that in both cases no error occurs:

```js
let global = undefined;

if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
  global = {
    proc: {
      trackingMarketExport: {},
    },
  };
}

(global?.proc?.trackingMarketExport ?? {}).started = true;

console.log(global);
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is short *enough*, but...

```
var started = ((global.proc) && (global.proc.trackingMarketExport))? true : false;
if (started) { global.proc.trackingMarketExport = started; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Check out the [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign?retiredLocale=de) method, which copies all properties to a target object and overrides it.

```
Object.assign(global, {
    proc: {
        trackingMarketExport: {
            started: true
        }
    }
})
```

Then you can just put it in one line:

```js
var globalDemo = {
 otherProperties: {
     a: 1,
     b: 2
 }
}

Object.assign(globalDemo, { proc: { trackingMarketExport: { started: true }}});

console.log(globalDemo);
console.log(globalDemo.proc.trackingMarketExport.started);
```

However, as mentioned in the comments, this technique will only work in your specific given scenario, because the other properties inside `proc` and `trackingMarketExport` will also be **overridden and therefore deleted**.

Comment: While this points the asker in the right direction a code sample showing how to use it would  make the answer a lot better!

Comment: Be careful with this strategy: `Object.assign` does not deep merge objects. This can overwrite other properties.

Comment: @jsejcksn Thanks, didn't think about that! Added the info to the question

Answer (score -1):

You could write something that walks the tree and sets an object if it does not exist. Many ways to write it.

```js
const setObj = (obj, path, value) => {
  const parts = path.split('.');
  const lastKey = parts.pop();
  const lastObj = parts.reduce((acc, key) => {
    acc[key] = acc[key] || {};
    return acc[key];
  }, obj);
  lastObj[lastKey] = value;
}

const path = 'proc.trackingMarketExport.started';
const value = false;

const x = {};
setObj(x, path, value);
console.log(x);

const y = {
  "proc": {
    "foo" : "baz",
    "trackingMarketExport": {
      "funky": {
        "boo" : "bah"
      }
    }
  }
};
setObj(y, path, value);
console.log(y);
```

while loop

```js
const setObj = (obj, path, value) => {
  const parts = path.split('.');
  let key;
  let walker = obj;
  while (key = parts.shift()) {
    walker[key] = parts.length ? (walker[key] || {}) : value;
    walker = walker[key];
  }
}

const path = 'proc.trackingMarketExport.started';
const value = false;

const x = {};
setObj(x, path, value);
console.log(x);

const y = {
  "proc": {
    "foo" : "baz",
    "trackingMarketExport": {
      "funky": {
        "boo" : "bah"
      }
    }
  }
};
setObj(y, path, value);
console.log(y);
```