# Creating nested objects in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

What's the easiest way to make nested objects in TypeScript? I want to be able to add elements in nested objects like this:

```
let dictionary: { [key: string]: { [key: string]: number  }  } = {};
dictionary['x']['y'] = 2
dictionary['x']['z'] = 5
```

I expect:

```
console.log(dictionary['x'])  // -> {'y': 2,'z': 5}

console.log(dictionary['x']['y'])  // -> 2
```

Comment: Start with `dictionary['x'] = {}`? Unless you use e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy the inner objects won't magically appear.

Comment: Related: [JavaScript: Write to dictionary if key doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67107996)

Comment: Yeah, this looks like a duplicate of that one to me.  Note that you could always write `(dictionary.x??={}).y = 2` as a one-liner, if you must

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that you are assigning the value `2` to the object at `dictionary['x']`, which resolves to `undefined`.

Try to initialise `dictionary['x'] = {}` first.