Safely setting a nested optional attribute in Typescript
In Typescript, I need to set a nested field in a type that similar to this one:
type NestedOptional = {
  a?: { b?: { c?: { d?: number; }; }; };
};

This requires a lot of boilerplate code to initialize all the non-leaves objects when needing to set the d leaf value. How can I avoid this?
function fillLeafValue(obj: NestedOptional, value: number) {
  // how can I avoid this boilerplate code when setting a value,
  // as does the JS optional chaining (?.) for getting values?
  if (obj.a == undefined) obj.a = {};
  if (obj.a.b == undefined) obj.a.b = {};
  if (obj.a.b.c == undefined) obj.a.b.c = {};
  obj.a.b.c.d = value;
}

I tried something like this:
// *** does not work: issue with generics recursion?
function ensure<T>(obj: T) {
  return function <K extends keyof T>(key: K, ctor: () => T[K]) {
    if (obj[key] == undefined) obj[key] = ctor();
    return ensure(obj[key]);
  };
}

// I wish I could use it like the following

const empty = () => ({}); // how to init the objects

function fillLeafValue2(obj: NestedOptional, value: number) {
  ensure(obj)("a", empty)("b", empty)("c", empty);
  //                       ^ Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
}

Also tried things like ts-get-set npm package but it's not strict enough: it allows setting "a.z.c" without an error for instance!
FWIW, I am actually using Immer JS with the produce method, but I still need to fill all optional layers of the draft.
Any advice? It looks like a pretty common case...

@jcalz doesn't initialise missing levels of that object. Only checks if they are there and then assigns the last level. OP wants to create the levels if they are missing and always assign the last value. See here which tackles for approaches. I have an answer there using function or a proxy for initialising and arbitrary keys at any arbitrary depth. However, ??=  is probably the right tool here for a known structure.

@VLAZ oh, of course. I misread. So (((obj.a ??= {}).b ??= {}).c ??= {}).d = value; is the lightweight solution without a general-purpose function (like proxy, etc). I'd suggest you write an answer unless this is a duplicate.

@VLAZ, that nullish coalescing assignment ??= is exactly what I was missing! Not sure who of you (or jcalz) should write the official answer, or if it's a duplicate somewhere, but I'll accept it! Thanks!
And thank you Derek for your support

Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74210981/creating-nested-objects-in-typescript, but it does not deal with the nesting and boilerplate code issue, and relates to a JS question that does not deal with type safety as far as I can tell.

Seems it's not easy to deal with recursion here, so I couldn't avoid as, but haven't worked much on that either. At least the function interface is good:
Playground
type NestedOptional = {
  a?: { b?: { c?: { d?: number; }; }; };
};

type Leaves<T> = T extends object ? { [K in keyof Required<T>]:
    K extends string ? `${K}${Leaves<T[K]> extends never ? "" : `.${Leaves<T[K]>}`}` : never
}[keyof T] : never

type ls = Leaves<NestedOptional>

type LeafValue<T, P extends Leaves<T>> = P extends keyof T ? T[P] : 
  P extends `${infer A}.${infer B}` ? 
    A extends keyof T ? B extends Leaves<T[A]> ? LeafValue<Required<T>[A], B> : never : never : never;

type SplitPath<T, P extends Leaves<T>> = P extends `${infer A}.${infer B}` ? A extends keyof T ? B extends Leaves<T[A]> ? [A, B] : [A, undefined] : never : never;

type sp = SplitPath<NestedOptional, 'a.b.c.d'>

function splitPath<T, P extends Leaves<T> = Leaves<T>>(path: P): SplitPath<T, P> {
  const [prop, ...ps] = path.split('.');
  return [prop, ps.join('.')] as SplitPath<T, P>;
}

function fillLeafValue<T, P extends Leaves<T>>(obj: T, path: P, value: LeafValue<T, P>) {
  const [prop, childPath] = splitPath<T>(path);
  if(!childPath){
    obj[prop] = value;
    return;
  }
  const child = obj[prop] ??= {} as T[typeof prop];
  fillLeafValue(child, childPath, value as LeafValue<typeof child, typeof childPath>);
}

const obj: NestedOptional = {};
fillLeafValue(obj, 'a.b.c.d', 1);
console.log(obj);


Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. I see that you take a similar approach to what @jcalz answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58436959/5690147 ... I like the simpler approach suggested in the comments of my question (I don't need the power of a generic dot notation actually) : (((obj.a ??= {}).b ??= {}).c ??= {}).d = value;

@YannVo just will leave my answer here for my own further reference. if my answer was somehow useful don't hesitate to upvote, thanks

As a solution for the doted syntax, your answer seems perfect for what I can tell, and this is what the direction I was researching towards initially! I guess you could just remove the sp and ls types that were likely only used for debug/devel : they make the solution less readable.
