# Vuex Method-style Access Getters

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js, vuex

I am having a bit hard time understanding the following JS:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    todos: [
      { id: 1, text: '...', done: true },
      { id: 2, text: '...', done: false }
    ]
  },
getters: {
  // ...
  getTodoById: (state) => (id) => {
    return state.todos.find(todo => todo.id === id)
  }
}
})

store.getters.getTodoById(2) // -> { id: 2, text: '...', done: false }
```

These two code snippets are taken from official Vuex Documentation [on Method Style Access for Getters](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#method-style-access).

Now what I dont understand is, how those the second part of code output the value in the comment? Maybe I miss-understood JS functions?

I believe the output would be:

```
(id) => {
  return state.todos.find(todo => todo.id === id)
}
```

So actually the second functions that is being returned, because in the call that they used, I do not see two `'()()'` nor do I understand from where does the function receive the `'state'` variable.

I would kindly like to ask for an explanation, whether I miss-understood something in JS, or is this something Vuex specific?

Comment: It's a javascript thing. This answer is a good explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32787782/11375753

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this for curried arrow function example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32787782/11375753

---

However, when we take this in consideration with the vuex getter method it works as follows.

```
getters: {
  getTodoById: (state) => (id) => {
    return state.todos.find(todo => todo.id === id)
  }
}
```

---

- We define a function in the property called `getToboById`.
- And we define another function when the first one is called. In the example `(id) => {}`. This will take our argument.
- The `(state)` part of the first declaration. If we take a regular getter without taking an argument. We always have access to the `state` argument. Vuex provides this for every getter function.
- So when we call the following: `store.getters.getTodoById(2)`. You are actually doing `store.getters.getTodoById()(2)`. Where in the first function call you will already contain the state.

So, to conclude:
This function call `store.getters.getTodoById()` will return us a function. Which we can call again with our argument.

And according to the linked example will look like:

```
  getTodoById: function(state) {
    return function(id) {
      return state.todos.find(todo => todo.id === id);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  I totally forgot about currying!

Answer (score -1):

This involves "the currying of functions", to put it simply:

```js
//①
const add = (x, y) => x + y;
add(2,3) // 5
```

The currying of this code will be:

```js
//②
const add = x => y => x + y;
```

and turn it into ES5 code would be like this:

```js
const add = function(x){
```

in that:

```js
getters: {
    //...
    getTodoById: (state) => (id) => {
        return state.todos.find(todo => todo.id === id)
    }
}
```

It can be written as its equivalent (just like ② and ① are equivalent):

```js
getters: {
    //...
    getTodoById: (state,id) => {
        return state.todos.find(todo => todo.id === id)
    }
}
```

The state parameter is the default parameter of getters, so you can call it like this:

```js
store.getters.getTodoById(2);
```

refer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67221323/12261182

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32787782/11375753