# How does this asyncHandler function work?

Tags: node.js, async-await, callback

I'm talking about this function:

```
const asyncHandler = (fn) => (req, res, next) => Promise.resolve(fn(req, res, next)).catch(next);
```

I am keen to understand step by step what is going on when we pass it this function:

```
getBootcamps = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const bootcamps = await Bootcamp.find();
  res.status(200).json({ success: true, count: bootcamps.length, data: bootcamps });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic) is a higher-order function that uses only function application and earlier defined combinators to define a result from its arguments.

So we have a combinator, `asyncHandler` -

```js
const asyncHandler = (fn) => (req, res, next) => Promise.resolve(fn(req, res, next)).catch(next)
```

And we have `getBootcamps` -

```js
const getBootcamps = asyncHandler(...)
```

So we fill in the definition of `asyncHandler` -

```js
const getBootcamps = (fn) => (req, res, next) =>
  Promise.resolve(fn(req, res, next)).catch(next)
```

Where the first argument, `fn`, is equal to -

```js
async (req, res, next) => {
  const bootcamps = await Bootcamp.find();
  res.status(200).json({ success: true, count: bootcamps.length, data: bootcamps });
}
```

So that becomes -

```js
const getBootcamps = (req, res, next) =>
  Promise.resolve((async (req, res, next) => {
    const bootcamps = await Bootcamp.find();
    res.status(200).json({ success: true, count: bootcamps.length, data: bootcamps });
  })(req, res, next)).catch(next)
```

So as `asyncHandler`'s name implies, it accepts a `fn` which is treated as an *async handler*. `fn` can return a promise and `asyncHandler` will properly wrap it and automatically connect the `next` callback to properly handle errors. Related: [*What do multiple arrow functions mean in JavaScript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32787782/633183)

This is an effective combinator because it prevents you from having to write this `try`-`catch` boilerplate for *every* async handler you would need -

```js
// without asyncHandler 

async function  getBootcamps (req, res, next) {
  try {
    const bootcamps = await Bootcamp.find()
    res.status(200).json({ success: true, count: bootcamps.length, data: bootcamps })
  }
  catch (err) {
    next(err)
  }
}
```

Instead `asyncHandler` allows you to focus on "success" path and automatically handles the "error" path for you -

```js
// with asyncHandler

const getBootcamps = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const bootcamps = await Bootcamp.find()
  res.status(200).json({ success: true, count: bootcamps.length, data: bootcamps })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

It generates a new function, based on existing function `fn`, with the signature:

```js
(req, res, next)
```

This generated function's body is:

```
return Promise.resolve(fn(req, res, next)).catch(next)
```

What it does is:

- call the `fn` (the underlying handler) with arguments `(req, res, next)`
- pass the return value of that `fn` call to Promise.resolve() - this converts it to a Promise if it wasn't one already
- register a callback (`next`) for when the promise rejects

The code that you've posted seems to be an [Adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) that converts an async function to work with `next(err)`-based error handling (most likely for the `express` framework). Notably, however, it only seems to care about the error case - it is still the async function's responsibility to send the response, thus ending the request processing.

Some other Web frameworks exist that make this step unnecessary - for instance, [fastify](https://www.fastify.io/) can just use async functions as handlers directly and simply return the response object instead of doing an explicit `.json()` call (which does `res.end()` under the hood).