# Is there a way to write a function that has some common logic?

Tags: javascript

So, I have these functions:

```
const myFunc1 = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  if (await dispatch(isSessionExpired())) return;

  const authToken = getAuthToken(getState());
  if(!authToken){
    dispatch(statuses.myFunc1Error());
    return;
  }

  //do something 
}

const myFunc2 = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  if (await dispatch(isSessionExpired())) return;

  const authToken = getAuthToken(getState());
  if(!authToken){
    dispatch(statuses.myFunc2Error());
    return;
  }

  //do something 
}

const myFunc3 = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  if (await dispatch(isSessionExpired())) return;

  const authToken = getAuthToken(getState());
  if(!authToken){
    dispatch(statuses.myFunc3Error());
    return;
  }

  //do something 
}
```

As you can see, there's a lot of repeated code, what's the best way to refactor this? I though doing something like this:

```
const creatorChecks = async (dispatch, getState, actionName) => {
    if (await dispatch(isSessionExpired())) return false;

    const authToken = getAuthToken(getState());
    if(!authToken){
      dispatch(statuses[`${actionName}Error`]());
      return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

and then...

```
const myFunc1 = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  if(!await creatorChecks(dispatch, getState, 'myFunc1')) return;
  // the code...
}

const myFunc2 = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  if(!await creatorChecks(dispatch, getState, 'myFunc2')) return;
  // the code...
}

const myFunc3 = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  if(!await creatorChecks(dispatch, getState, 'myFunc3')) return;
  // the code...
}
```

But maybe there's a better way...

Comment: Note that `creatorChecks` is async, it'll have be awaited to assess the bool

Comment: Oh yes @JonathanHamel I forgot that

Comment: If the code you have works, and you're willing to share more of it, you may want to check their [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) to see if your question is on topic for [codereview.se].

Comment: Seems like that is about as clean as you will get it.

Answer (score 0):

Extract your common logic into a function and take the error producer and actual code to use as callbacks. That gives you a common algorithm for all with interchangeable parts of the implementation:

```js
const decorate = errFn => fn => () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  if (await dispatch(isSessionExpired())) return;

  const authToken = getAuthToken(getState());
  if(!authToken){
    dispatch(errFn());
    return;
  }

  return fn(dispatch, getState);
}


const myFunc1 = decorate
    (statuses.myFunc1Error)
    (async (dispatch, getState) => { 
        /* do something 1 */ 
    });

const myFunc2 = decorate
    (statuses.myFunc2Error)
    (async (dispatch, getState) => { 
        /* do something 2 */ 
    });

const myFunc3 = decorate
    (statuses.myFunc3Error)
    (async (dispatch, getState) => { 
        /* do something 3 */ 
    });
```

This works very similarly to [the template method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) but implemented with just functions without classes.

---

The implementation above takes the dependencies in [curried form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32782922/what-do-multiple-arrow-functions-mean-in-javascript) but it can also be changed to take all of them as parameters.

```
const decorate = (errFn, fn) => () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
```

which means the call has to be changed like this:

```
const myFunc1 = decorate
    (statuses.myFunc1Error,
    async (dispatch, getState) => { 
        /* do something 1 */ 
    });
```

I personally prefer the curried version as it makes it easier to distinguish where parameters start and end, thanks to the matching brackets highlight feature in editors.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, is there a benefit of doing it this way rather than the one I suggested?

Comment: @nick well, you don't have to keep adding the `if` to each of your functions. The only logic you write is the one that matters, the check is automatically added without having to add it. But otherwise, it's fundamentally the same - refactor the common code into a common reusable function.