# How do I convert array to an array object and combine two arrays to a one array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const absentStudentsId = [78, 15, 41, 30] // ======> [{stdId: 78, isPresent: false}, {stdId: 15, isPresent: false}, {stdId: 41, isPresent: false}, {stdId: 30, isPresent: false}]

const presentStudentsId = [80, 61] // ======> [{stdId: 80, isPresent: true}, {stdId: 61, isPresent: true}]

const students = [
  { stdId: 78, isPresent: false },
  { stdId: 15, isPresent: false },
  { stdId: 41, isPresent: false },
  { stdId: 30, isPresent: false },
  { stdId: 80, isPresent: true },
  { stdId: 61, isPresent: true },
]
```

I want to implement that logic as you see in the commented line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) -> loop over array elements and return a new item for eachitem with your desired computation.

[...(Spread)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) -> spread operator which expands an array into individual elements.

```
let ans = [...(absentStudentsId.map(x => { return { stdId : x, present : false} })),...(presentStudentsId.map(x => {return { stdId : x, present : true} }))]
```

Answer (score 8):

You could take a closure over `isPresent` and map new objects.

```js
const
    buildObject = isPresent => stdId => ({ stdId, isPresent }),
    absentStudentsId = [78, 15, 41, 30],
    presentStudentsId = [80, 61],
    students = [
        ...absentStudentsId.map(buildObject(false)),
        ...presentStudentsId.map(buildObject(true))
    ];
    
console.log(students);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Great answer, can you explain `buildObject = isPresent => stdId => ({ stdId, isPresent }),` this line? I am guessing `isPresent` is the `false` or `true` you passed inside `buildObject` and `stdId` is passed by the map function itself?

Comment: @SinanYaman correct. [It's a curried function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32782922/what-do-multiple-arrow-functions-mean-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const absentStudentsId = [78, 15, 41, 30] // ======> [{stdId: 78, isPresent: false}, {stdId: 15, isPresent: false}, {stdId: 30, isPresent: false}]

const presentStudentsId = [80, 61] // ======> [{stdId: 80, isPresent: true}, {stdId: 61, isPresent: true}]

const transformStudents = (students, isPresent) => students.map(studentId => ({ stdId: studentId, isPresent}));

const allStudents = [...transformStudents(absentStudentsId, false), ...transformStudents(presentStudentsId, true)];

console.log(allStudents)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another straightforward solution:

```
const absentStudentsId = [78, 15, 41, 30]
const presentStudentsId = [80, 61]

const students = []
absentStudentsId.forEach(id => students.push({stdID: id, isPresent: false}))
presentStudentsId.forEach(id => students.push({stdID: id, isPresent: true}))

console.log(students)
/*
[
  { stdID: 78, isPresent: false },
  { stdID: 15, isPresent: false },
  { stdID: 41, isPresent: false },
  { stdID: 30, isPresent: false },
  { stdID: 80, isPresent: true },
  { stdID: 61, isPresent: true }
]
*/
```