# ES6 fat arrow function arguments unable to comprehend

Tags: javascript, callback, ecmascript-6

Can anyone clearly explain how arguments are being passed to "log" function and then to "add" functions in the following code.

```
const add = (x,y) => console.log(x+y);

const log = func => (...args) => {
  console.log(...args);
  func(...args);
}

const logadd = log(add);
logadd(1,2,3); // 3 //1,2,3
```

I know the above code can also be written as follows

```
const add = function(x,y) {
  console.log(x,y);
}

const log = function(func){
   return function(...args){
    console.log(...args);
    func(...args)
  }       
}

const logadd=log(add);
logadd(1,2,3); // 3 //1,2,3
```

If logadd is function variable and if I pass it arguments how are the arguments passed to, first log function and then to add function? Any nice articles that explain this or can anyone explain this?

Comment: Hints: *Currying function, spread operator*

Comment: If you understood the bottom variant, understanding the top one is simple: `func => ___` is (mostly) equivalent to `function(func) { ___ }`, and `(...args) => ___` is (mostly) equivalent to `function(...args) { ___ }`. With those substitutions, the two code blocks are literally a copy-paste of each other.

Comment: Hi @Amadan  I understand what you explained and with that understanding only I wrote the first block is the same as second block. However what I didn't understand is how the args were passed through to inner function magically?

Comment: @Rajesh thanks I will look into Currying function

Comment: I am not sure why this question has been down voted? can anyone care to explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all arrow functions are just called arrow functions - they are neither fat nor thin.

In `func => (...args)` the `args` argument is used as a rest parameter (indicated by `...`) to collect all given arguments in an `Array` (`[1,2,3]` in your example). With `console.log(...args)` the spread syntax `...` is used to apply the `console.log` method to all elements of the `args` array. Please note that the meaning of the `...` syntax varies depending on the context.

`func(...args)` is evaluated to `func(1,2,3)`. Since `func` represents `add`, it discards the third argument.

`log` is a higher order function, i.e. a function that takes another function as its argument. This has nothing to do with currying, though currying facilitates the use of higher order functions. However, `log` is partially applicable in its first argument.

Comment: Thanks @ftor, that makes sense. The missing link in my understanding was High order functions. Do you suggest any good articles to read more about these?

Comment: Of course: [function composition](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30198265/6445533) is one of the most important higher order functions. This is a good starting point. There are many more though.