# callback, err: is not a function

Tags: javascript, callback, currying

So I am going back to some of the basics and found that I am having trouble with the simplest of things. I have a callback that is throwing me an error, I suspect this is a hoisting thing, but have been googling and can't seem to find what I am looking for.

```
function add (a,b){return a+b;}
function multiply (a,b){return a*b;}


function applyFn(callback) {
    return callback;
};

var f = applyFn(add);

console.log(f); //logs => function add(a,b){return a+b;}

f(3)(4); // returns => Uncaught TypeError: f(...) is not a function(…)
```

I know that `var f` gets hoisted to the top with a value of undefined, while the named functions are hoisted intact. When I console log `console.log(typeof f)` it returns `function` - so I am a little confused about what is going on...am I on the right track, or is it a different issue completely?

EDIT: 
for more clarity the applyFn was supposed to be able to use either the `add` or `multiply`function, and so it would look more like this:

```
function add (a,b){return a+b;}
function multiply (a,b){return a*b;}

//I needed to write this function, but nothing else
function applyFn(callback) {
    return function(){};
};

var f = applyFn(add);
var x = applyFn(multiply)

f(3)(4);
x(6)(8);
```

Comment: could you please eloberate a bit on why you say `f(3)(4)` and not `f(3,4)`?

Comment: Are you looking for function `currying`?

Comment: @ EagleRainbow actually this was how the function was called in a coding challenge so I can't give you a straight answer on that - I do know that I have seen it before, but I don't recall exactly why it was done when I saw it.

Comment: Once you call f, it doesn't return a function, it returns the result of the function passed to applyFn.

Comment: @ KevBot I might be, maybe this is why my google search wasn't getting me anywhere. searching for the wrong thing. will check that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, you need to look at what `applyFn` returns. It takes a function, and simply returns that function. If you assign what it returns, the variable that you assigned to is now simply a reference to the function you originally passed in. In this case, that's the function `add` and it simply adds two numbers together. When you call `f`, you're really calling `add`, which means 1. it needs two arguments and 2. it's going to return the result of adding the two arguments, not another function that you can then call. If your goal is to do currying, then your function needs to return another function, so that it can be invoked:

```
function adder(num1) {
  return function (num2) {
    return num1 + num2;
  };
}

adder(2)(3);
```

Here is what I think you're looking for:

```
function applyFn(func) {
  return function (x) {
    return function (y) {
      return func(x, y);
    };
  };
}
```

This implementation of applyFn should do what you expect with `add` and `multiply`

Comment: ahhh that makes it a little clearer - but I am still not 'there' yet... the `applyFn` was supposed to be able to be passed either the `add` or `multiply` function. so there were actually two calls (although I only included one) i will edit my question to make it more clear

Comment: Ok, now I understand. Give me a minute and I'll update my answer to show what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: `If your goal is to do currying, then your function needs to return another function, so that it can be invoked` thank you! This solution works. I didn't realize that my problem was a currying, and  am now reading up on that and studying your answer :)

Comment: @HolyMoly `applyFn` is actually currying of a binary function. The succinct arrow syntax is suitable for currying functions manually: `const add = x => y => x + y` and `const curry2 => f => a => b => f(a, b)`. Currying is a broad subject: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30249365/5536315

Answer (score 1):

your code is not failing at `f(3)`, but at the second call. `f(3)` is not a function, so `f(3)(4)` fails.
applyFn should something be more like this:

```
var applyFn = fn => a => b => fn(a,b);
//aka.
function applyFn(fn){
    return function(a){
        return function(b){
            return fn(a, b);
        }
    }
}
```

but this is a pretty limited implementation, since it only works on functions with exactly two arguments. Better would be something more dynamically, like:

```
function _curry(n, f, a){
    var c = function(...args){
        var b = a.concat(args);
        return b.length < n? _curry(n, f, b): f.apply(this, b);
    }
    Object.defineProperty(c, "length", { configurable: true, value: Math.max(0, n-a.length) });
    return c;
}

function curry(n, f, a){
    if(typeof n === "function") a=f, f=n, n=f.length;
    return _curry(n, f, Array.from(Object(a)));
}

var add = curry(function(a, b){ return a + b });

console.log(add, add(3), add(3)(4), add(3, 4));
```

but on the other hand, the `add` and `multiply`-methods don't make sense, the way they are implemented at the moment. 
I would never favor `add(foo)(bar)` or even `add(foo, bar)` over `foo + bar`.

the only place where they make sense is in a context like:

```
arr.map( add(3) );
//or
promise.then( add(3) );
```

so why not implement them directly as

```
var add = b => a => a+b;
var multiply = b => a => a*b;
```

and skip the part with applyFn?

```
//why b=>a instead of a=>b? consistency:
var subtract = b => a => a-b;
//so that subtract(3) also does exactly what you would think it does
```

Comment: Wow @Thomas, thank you so much for expanding on this for me! It gives me a lot to consider. The reason the original problem is written the way it was is because it was part of a coding challenge and all I was to do was create the `applyFn` function.  I have never seen the syntax `var applyFn = fn => a => b => fn(a,b);` and would like to learn more about it - can you tell me what term I should be googling to learn more about that? I like the dynamic implementation (although it wasn't necessary for the challenge, but would have been impressive)! Overall, a great addition to the convo, thank you!

Comment: I don't know wether this type of "chaining" lambdas has a name, it's something I came across when learning about functional programming. The Arrow itself has a name: "lambda-expression" or "fat-arrow". But since it is ES6 you'll need a preprocessor like [Babel](//babeljs.io/repl) to use it in production.

Comment: "_the only place where they make sense is in a context like:_". Ya, currying makes composing of functions much easier and that's really a big deal. That's why `Promise` is composable. Actually this is the crucial point in functional programming.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for executing `f` is wrong. `f(3)(4)` should be `f(3, 4)`. Checked it and it works. Check [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pxfpwvf8/)

Comment: yes f(3,4) will work - and that makes sense. to put in context, this was part of a coding challenge. the thing i was supposed to do was create the `applyFn` function so that the calls to `f` would work. those calls were already defined. With that said, although modifying the calls to f works - I am not sure if that was what was expected of me. Any thoughts? do you think it was an error on the creators of the challenge, or was there another way to make this run without modifying the call?